# How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I have classes like these:

```
class MyDate
{
    int year, month, day;
}

class Lad
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    MyDate dateOfBirth;
}
```

And I would like to turn a `Lad` object into a **JSON** string like this:

```
{
    "firstName":"Markoff",
    "lastName":"Chaney",
    "dateOfBirth":
    {
        "year":"1901",
        "month":"4",
        "day":"30"
    }
}
```

(Without the formatting). I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), but it uses a namespace that's not in **.NET 4**. I also heard about [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), but their site seems to be down at the moment, and I'm not keen on using external DLL files.

Are there other options besides manually creating a **JSON** string writer?

Comment: JSON.net can be loaded [here](http://json.codeplex.com/) An other and faster (as they say - I did not test it myself) solution is [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#readme) I would not recommend rolling your own JSON parser. It will likely be slower and more error prone or you have to invest lots of time.

Comment: yes. C# has a type called JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generics / JSON JavaScriptSerializer C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304081/generics-json-javascriptserializer-c)

Comment: Hm.. as far as I can see you should be able to use:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx Which is also in .Net 4.0 according to the MSDN page. You should be able to use the Serialize(Object obj) method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292287.aspx Am I missing something here? Btw. you link seems to be a some code and not a link

Answer (score 1025, accepted):

### Please Note

**Microsoft recommends that you DO NOT USE JavaScriptSerializer**

See the header of the documentation page:

> For .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions, use the APIs in the System.Text.Json namespace for serialization and deserialization. For earlier versions of .NET Framework, use Newtonsoft.Json.

---

##### Original answer:

You could use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer) class (add reference to `System.Web.Extensions`):

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

A full example:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class MyDate
{
    public int year;
    public int month;
    public int day;
}

public class Lad
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public MyDate dateOfBirth;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new Lad
        {
            firstName = "Markoff",
            lastName = "Chaney",
            dateOfBirth = new MyDate
            {
                year = 1901,
                month = 4,
                day = 30
            }
        };
        var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have in mind that Microsoft suggests to use JSON.net instead of this solution. I think that this answer became inappropriate. Take a look at willsteel's answer. Source: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

Comment: @DarinDimitrov you should consider adding a hint about JSON.net. Microsoft recommends it over JavascriptSerializer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx You could also add a hint to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx which is the framework included approach

Comment: [here](http://csharp2json.azurewebsites.net/) is **online tool** to convert your `classes` to `json` format, hope helps someone.

Comment: using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

Comment: Why would Microsoft recommend a 3rd party solution over their own? Their wording is very odd as well: "Json.NET should be used serialization and deserialization. Provides serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications."

Comment: but this solution not return number as string...
please tell me a solution same of **javascript stringify**, that it convert any key:value to string. 
my problem is with **number**.

Comment: Just a heads up, to reference to `System.Web.Extensions`, you must have `ASP.NET AJAX 1.0` or `ASP.NET 3.5` installed on your system. Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723489/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-web-extensions-version-1-0-61025-0-erro

Comment: Is there any way to print the object creat in a cshtml page, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1449):

**Since we all love one-liners**

... this one depends on the Newtonsoft NuGet package, which is popular and better than the default serializer.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {foo = "bar"})
```

Documentation: **[Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)**

Comment: Newtonsoft serializer is way faster and mor customizable then built in. Highly recommend to use it. Thanks for the answer @willsteel

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it's not really free. See /pricing on the website.

Comment: @JosefPfleger the pricing is for JSON.NET Schema, not JSON.NET the regular serializer, which is MIT

Comment: My testing showed that Newtonsoft is slower than JavaScriptSerializer class. (.NET 4.5.2)

Comment: If you read the MSDN documentation for [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), it flat out says use JSON.net.

Comment: @JosefPfleger Newtionsoft JSON.net is MIT licensed... you could make modifications and resell it it you wanted. Their pricing page is about commercial technical support, and some schema validator they have.

Comment: With `JavaScriptSerializer` DateTime property was serialized as `"date": "/Date(1490648400000)/"` and was causing deserialized date to be a day back .In `Newtonsof` was `"date": "2017-03-29T00:00:00"` and solved my problem.

Comment: For everyone reading this, do note that this answer is very very old. Although Newtonsoft.Json is still very popular, and does the job, do consider using the new (built in) System.Text.Json which is mentioned in other answers

Comment: Newtonsoft is for earlier versions of 4.7.2 .NET Framework

Answer (score 136):

Use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/) library, you can download it from Nuget Packet Manager.

**Serializing to Json String:**

```
 var obj = new Lad
        {
            firstName = "Markoff",
            lastName = "Chaney",
            dateOfBirth = new MyDate
            {
                year = 1901,
                month = 4,
                day = 30
            }
        };

var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

**Deserializing to Object:**

```
var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lad>(jsonString );
```

Answer (score 75):

A new JSON serializer is available in the `System.Text.Json` namespace. It's included in the .NET Core 3.0 shared framework and is in a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) for projects that target .NET Standard or .NET Framework or .NET Core 2.x.

Example code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

public class MyDate
{
    public int year { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
}

public class Lad
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public MyDate DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var lad = new Lad
        {
            FirstName = "Markoff",
            LastName = "Chaney",
            DateOfBirth = new MyDate
            {
                year = 1901,
                month = 4,
                day = 30
            }
        };
        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(lad);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

In this example the classes to be serialized have properties rather than fields; the `System.Text.Json` serializer currently doesn't serialize fields.

Documentation:

- [System.Text.Json overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview)
- [How to use System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)

Comment: Side notes: (1) in order to manage a json serialization the properties of the class must have at least getters, (2) `JsonSerializer.Serialize(lad)` prints all in one line; if you want to get an indented printout use the json `options`, (3) I would rather override `ToString()` in the class itself, so that you have never have to write again the whole `JsonSerializer.Serialize(lad)` sentence, just put inside the class this: `public override string ToString() => JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });`

Comment: "the `System.Text.Json` serializer currently doesn't serialize fields." Well, it can if you use `JsonSerializer.Serialize(lad, new JsonSerializerOptions { IncludeFields = true });`. Used in conjunction with @PaulEfford's comment, you can get a class that includes fields, as well as indenting the JSON

Answer (score 65):

Use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class: [MSDN1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), [MSDN2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx).

My example: [HERE](http://pastebin.com/8Wyn9K7F).

It can also safely deserialize objects from a JSON string, unlike `JavaScriptSerializer`. But personally I still prefer [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: Still don't see any examples on *that page*, but here are some on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx) and [elsewhere](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2009/12/29/json-serialization-using-the-datacontractjsonserializer-and-c/) -> the last one uses extension methods to achieve one-liners.

Comment: Oh, I missed the 2nd MSDN link  :)

Comment: It doesn't serialize plain classes. The error reported "Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute."

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim That's right, you have to mark properties in the class you want to serialize with attributes. [DataContractAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) [DataMemberAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Edgar: this is why JavaScriptSerializer better :)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim Which is better depends on the requirements. The attributes let you configure how the property is serialized.

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializer is very bad because it requires attributes to be set for any type (e.g. library objects).

Answer (score 38):

You can achieve this by using Newtonsoft.json. Install Newtonsoft.json from NuGet. And then:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 26):

Wooou! Really better using a JSON framework :)

Here is my example using Json.NET (http://james.newtonking.com/json):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace com.blogspot.jeanjmichel.jsontest.model
{
    public class Contact
    {
        private Int64 id;
        private String name;
        List<Address> addresses;

        public Int64 Id
        {
            set { this.id = value; }
            get { return this.id; }
        }

        public String Name
        {
            set { this.name = value; }
            get { return this.name; }
        }

        public List<Address> Addresses
        {
            set { this.addresses = value; }
            get { return this.addresses; }
        }

        public String ToJSONRepresentation()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));

            jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jw.WriteStartObject();
            jw.WritePropertyName("id");
            jw.WriteValue(this.Id);
            jw.WritePropertyName("name");
            jw.WriteValue(this.Name);

            jw.WritePropertyName("addresses");
            jw.WriteStartArray();

            int i;
            i = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < addresses.Count; i++)
            {
                jw.WriteStartObject();
                jw.WritePropertyName("id");
                jw.WriteValue(addresses[i].Id);
                jw.WritePropertyName("streetAddress");
                jw.WriteValue(addresses[i].StreetAddress);
                jw.WritePropertyName("complement");
                jw.WriteValue(addresses[i].Complement);
                jw.WritePropertyName("city");
                jw.WriteValue(addresses[i].City);
                jw.WritePropertyName("province");
                jw.WriteValue(addresses[i].Province);
                jw.WritePropertyName("country");
                jw.WriteValue(addresses[i].Country);
                jw.WritePropertyName("postalCode");
                jw.WriteValue(addresses[i].PostalCode);
                jw.WriteEndObject();
            }

            jw.WriteEndArray();

            jw.WriteEndObject();

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public Contact()
        {
        }

        public Contact(Int64 id, String personName, List<Address> addresses)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = personName;
            this.addresses = addresses;
        }

        public Contact(String JSONRepresentation)
        {
            //To do
        }
    }
}
```

The test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using com.blogspot.jeanjmichel.jsontest.model;

namespace com.blogspot.jeanjmichel.jsontest.main
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
            addresses.Add(new Address(1, "Rua Dr. Fernandes Coelho, 85", "15º andar", "São Paulo", "São Paulo", "Brazil", "05423040"));
            addresses.Add(new Address(2, "Avenida Senador Teotônio Vilela, 241", null, "São Paulo", "São Paulo", "Brazil", null));

            Contact contact = new Contact(1, "Ayrton Senna", addresses);

            Console.WriteLine(contact.ToJSONRepresentation());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Ayrton Senna",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "streetAddress": "Rua Dr. Fernandes Coelho, 85",
      "complement": "15º andar",
      "city": "São Paulo",
      "province": "São Paulo",
      "country": "Brazil",
      "postalCode": "05423040"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "streetAddress": "Avenida Senador Teotônio Vilela, 241",
      "complement": null,
      "city": "São Paulo",
      "province": "São Paulo",
      "country": "Brazil",
      "postalCode": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I will implement the constructor method that will receives a JSON string and populates the class' fields.

Comment: Good post, this is the most current way to do it.

Comment: I guess one expects to find a unit test under "The test" section, whereas there is none. btw, I like the approach where the `Contact` object knows how to convert itself to JSON. What I don't like in this example, is that the object is not actually an object from OOP perspective, rather than just bunch of public methods and properties.

Comment: "`com.blogspot.jeanjmichel.jsontest.main`" Ah, a Java programmer falls to the dark side. Welcome. We have cookies.

Comment: Hahahahaha yes @Corey =)

Answer (score 11):

If they are not very big, what's probably your case export it as JSON.

Also this makes it portable among all platforms.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[TestMethod]
public void ExportJson()
{
    double[,] b = new double[,]
        {
            { 110,  120,  130,  140, 150 },
            {1110, 1120, 1130, 1140, 1150},
            {1000,    1,   5,     9, 1000},
            {1110,    2,   6,    10, 1110},
            {1220,    3,   7,    11, 1220},
            {1330,    4,   8,    12, 1330}
        };

    string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(b);

    Console.WriteLine(jsonStr);

    string path = "X:\\Programming\\workspaceEclipse\\PyTutorials\\src\\tensorflow_tutorials\\export.txt";

    File.WriteAllText(path, jsonStr);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In your Lad model class, add an override to the  **ToString()** method that returns a JSON string version of your Lad object.
Note: you will need to import **System.Text.Json**;

```
using System.Text.Json;

class MyDate
{
    int year, month, day;
}

class Lad
{
    public string firstName { get; set; };
    public string lastName { get; set; };
    public MyDate dateOfBirth { get; set; };
    public override string ToString() => JsonSerializer.Serialize<Lad>(this);
}
```

Comment: `JsonSerializer.Serialize<Lad>(this)` can be simplified to `JsonSerializer.Serialize(this)`

Comment: Side notes: (1) in order to manage a json serialization the properties of the class must have at least getters, (2) `JsonSerializer.Serialize(lad)` prints all in one line; if you want to get an indented printout use the json `options`, (3) I would rather override `ToString()` like this: `public override string ToString() => JsonSerializer.Serialize(this, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });`

Answer (score 8):

If you are in an ASP.NET MVC web controller it's as simple as:

```
string ladAsJson = Json(Lad);
```

Can't believe no one has mentioned this.

Comment: I get an error about not being able to cast jsonresult to string.

Comment: It will compile with implicit typing: var ladAsJson = Json(Lad).

Answer (score 8):

## October 2023 update:

Another solution using built-in `System.Text.Json` (.NET Core 3.0+) where an **object is self-sufficient** and doesn't expose all possible fields:

A passing test (using NUnit):

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Intech.UnitTests
{
    public class UserTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void ConvertsItselfToJson()
        {
            var userName = "John";
            var user = new User(userName);

            var actual = user.ToJson();

            Assert.AreEqual($"{{\"Name\":\"{userName}\"}}", actual);
        }
    }
}
```

An implementation:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Intech
{
    public class User
    {
        private readonly string name;

        public User(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public string ToJson()
        {
            var params = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"Name", name}};
            return JsonSerializer.Serialize(params);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having to write code in a VM not connected to the internet, so this is very useful.

Answer (score 6):

I would vote for ServiceStack's JSON Serializer:

```
using ServiceStack;

string jsonString = new { FirstName = "James" }.ToJson();
```

It is also the fastest JSON serializer available for .NET:
http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/

Comment: Those are very old benchmarks there. I've just test all three current versions of Newtonsoft, ServiceStack and JavaScriptSerializer and currently Newtonsoft is the fastest. Tho they all do quite fast.

Comment: ServiceStack doesn't appear to be free.

Comment: @joelnet this is now the case, but was free when answering the question. However it is free for small sites, and I am still using it even though it is paid, it is a superb framework.

Comment: Some benchmarks here, though there's non for the serialization on its own: http://docs.servicestack.net/real-world-performance

Comment: @joelnet Seems to be free now. Don't know when they changed it.

Answer (score 3):

It is as easy as this (it works for dynamic objects as well (type object)):

```
string json = new
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(MYOBJECT);
```

Comment: there is no default script under web. :(

Comment: You are looking for this:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I kind of tried that but no. Script I guess I should add it as reference. So thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/) - an open source library

```
public class MyDate
{
    public int year { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
}

public class Lad
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public MyDate dateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

static void ToJsonString()
{
    var obj = new Lad
    {
        firstName = "Tom",
        lastName = "Smith",
        dateOfBirth = new MyDate
        {
            year = 1901,
            month = 4,
            day = 30
        }
    };
    var json = ChoJSONWriter.Serialize<Lad>(obj);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "firstName": "Tom",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "dateOfBirth": {
    "year": 1901,
    "month": 4,
    "day": 30
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library.

Answer (score 0):

**Serializer**

```
 public static void WriteToJsonFile<T>(string filePath, T objectToWrite, bool append = false) where T : new()
{
        var contentsToWriteToFile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToWrite, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        });
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, append))
        {
            writer.Write(contentsToWriteToFile);
        }
}
```

**Object**

```
namespace MyConfig
{
    public class AppConfigurationSettings
    {
        public AppConfigurationSettings()
        {
            /* initialize the object if you want to output a new document
             * for use as a template or default settings possibly when 
             * an app is started.
             */
            if (AppSettings == null) { AppSettings=new AppSettings();}
        }

        public AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppSettings
    {
        public bool DebugMode { get; set; } = false;
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
var jsonObject = new AppConfigurationSettings();
WriteToJsonFile<AppConfigurationSettings>(file.FullName, jsonObject);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "DebugMode": false
  }
}
```