# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0 Error

Tags: asp.net, system.web.extensions

I have check this site for solutions but i didn't find something that can help me..
My Host Diabled the Custom Error on their Server, So now i can see the real errors.

My web site was working flawless in the **old Host**, But now i Moved to a **new host**

**Please pay attention:** The **Old host** was a **VPS** on ***NetVison host***

So i'v stoped paying him and **now** i'm hosting on the **same *NetVision* host** as a **shared host**.

So I moved all the files in to the **root folder** and config the SQL details in the **Web.config**

I can't load the site for some reason.
i got Errors all the time.
**PLEASE HELP ME!**

**The Error I get:**

## Server Error in '/' Application.

### Configuration Error

#### Parser Error Message:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions,
Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of
its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

#### Source Error:

```
Line 49:            <assemblies>
Line 50:                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
Line 51:                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>*
Line 52:            </assemblies>
Line 53:        </compilation>
```

#### Source File:

\filer\Sites\NV355601\www.picit.co.il\www\web.config    **Line: 51**

***MY Web.Config:***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="SiteAddress" value="http://www.picit.co.il/" />
    <add key="SSLSiteAddress" value="https://bonsite-secure.co.il/picit/" />

    <add key="EMAIL_HOST" value="mail.barak.net.il"/>
    <add key="EMAIL_CONTACT_NAME" value="PicIt"/>
    <add key="EMAIL_USER" value="bonsite-barak.net.il"/>
    <add key="EMAIL_PASS" value="013013"/>
    <add key="MASTER_USERNAME" value="bonsite"/>
    <add key="MASTER_PASSWORD" value="master123#"/>

    <add key="FCKeditor:UserFilesPath" value="~/Up/Main/"/>
    <add key="FCKeditor:BasePath" value="~/Controls/FCKeditor/"/>
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Con" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=db;user=usr;password=pwd;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="he-IL" uiCulture="he-IL"/>
    <sessionState mode="InProc"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="22000"
minFreeThreads="16"
executionTimeout="500"
useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
appRequestQueueLimit="1000" />
    <pages theme="Front">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="Website"/>
        </namespaces>
        <controls>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI" tagPrefix="asp"/>
            <add tagPrefix="Upload" namespace="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" assembly="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload"/>
            <add tagPrefix="fck" namespace="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2"/>
            <add tagPrefix="swf" tagName="movie" src="~/Controls/swf.ascx"/>
            <add tagPrefix="Btn" tagName="Friend" src="~/Controls/btn_friend.ascx"/>
            <add assembly="Bound" namespace="CustomControls" tagPrefix="asp"/>
            <add assembly="skmValidators" namespace="skmValidators" tagPrefix="Vld"/>

            <add tagPrefix="CC" tagName="Upload" src="~/Controls/upload.ascx"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="UploadHttpModule" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="GET" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="UploadHttpModule" type="Brettle.Web.NeatUpload.UploadHttpModule, Brettle.Web.NeatUpload" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="ScriptResource.axd_GET" path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET" type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource.axd_GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <add name="*.asmx_*" path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## Thanks ALL FOR YOUR HELP!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to ask to your host for `ASP.NET 3.5` framework support.

Comment: or, if I remember correctly, if using a lower framework (no reason you should be) its installed via the Ajax control toolkit.

Comment: Is **Ajax** is installed on server?

Comment: .NET Applications (ASPX) ( .NET UP 3.5 .)
 I can't Install on the server. But i will check if Ajax is Installed

Comment: Ok. After a long talk on the phone.. It's seems that they are not sure if they have Ajax support on a shared host account. Is there a way to check if I have an Ajax supprt on my Host? btw... could it be a Version problem?

Comment: @Ofear - That error/exception itself describes this issue. I'm sure about it. You can add appropriate version of Ajax dll into Bin folder.

Comment: where can i find this Dll file?

Comment: OK. I put an Ajax Control Toolkit Sample Site on the HOST. I have change the file permission to 777 and now i see the Ajax sample site. So i think i have AJAX support on my host... Please refer to this link: http://picit.co.il/Default.aspx So Maybe it's something worng with my Web.config?

Comment: Read this thread - http://forums.asp.net/t/1135367.aspx and http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ppsmonitoringandanalytics/thread/2342d477-ae97-4e5a-a778-19ff69af1a87/

Comment: You both are rights, but i added the DLL to my BIN directory and now it's kinda FIXED. Now i have a new problem Thanks mate!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762204/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occu

Answer (score 38):

Install *Ajax Extensions 1.0* from [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=883)

I have faced this error most of time due to this not being installed.

Comment: I can't Install on the server. it's a Shared Server... Thanks!

Comment: do u have simple hosting or VPS like server ?

Comment: if there is framework 4.0 then set it and check again..

Comment: ask hoster for install AjaxExtetion 1.0

Comment: I'm calling now.. i hope they will do it...

Comment: Ok. After a long talk on the phone.. It's seems that they are not sure if they have Ajax support on a shared host account. Is there a way to check if I have an Ajax supprt on my Host? btw... could it be a Version problem?

Comment: yah this problem occur when 1) does not have .net framework 3.5 or more or 2) Ajax Extensions 1.0 no installed in server.

Comment: I have .net framework 3.5, Is there any html file that i can run on the host to test the ajax support?

Comment: no, for this issue you have to test demo which include Ajax Control Tookit like calender extender.

Comment: OK. I put an Ajax Control Toolkit Sample Site on the HOST. I have change the file permission to 777 and now i see the Ajax sample site. So i think i have AJAX support on my host... Please refer to this link: http://picit.co.il/Default.aspx So Maybe it's something worng with my Web.config?

Comment: so now i am sure that ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions 1.0  is not installed in your server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4165/discussion-between-bhargav-mistri-and-ofear)

Comment: if you want to test your site, i can provide you sample space from my server for test.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! i manage to fix the Ajax problem by adding the right version Dll. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762204/a-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the-server-but-then-an-error-occu

Comment: thank you. This solved my problem. When we moved an old .Net v2 project to new servers. God damn lecacy applications!