# Convert object to JSON string in C#

Tags: c#, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)

In the Java, I have a code to convert java object to JSON string. How to do the similar in the C# ? which JSON library I should use ?

Thanks.

JAVA code

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

public class ReturnData {
    int total;

    List<ExceptionReport> exceptionReportList;  

    public String getJSon(){
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 

        json.put("totalCount", total);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for(ExceptionReport report : exceptionReportList){
            JSONObject jsonTmp = new JSONObject();
            jsonTmp.put("reportId", report.getReportId());      
            jsonTmp.put("message", report.getMessage());            
            jsonArray.add(jsonTmp);         
        }

        json.put("reports", jsonArray);
        return json.toString();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You should give this a try in C# and show us the code that you're trying.  As written, this question is little more than a google search away from an answer, and doesn't add value above that.  Please edit your question to include what you've tried in C#, and what isn't working.

Comment: @George Stocker He is asking about serializing and you are showing duplicate of deserializing, why?

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya Out of the myriad of duplicates, I misread and chose the wrong one. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I have used [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) ([Documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/)) It allows you to create a class / object, populate the fields, and serialize as JSON.

```
public class ReturnData 
{
    public int totalCount { get; set; }
    public List<ExceptionReport> reports { get; set; }  
}

public class ExceptionReport
{
    public int reportId { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }  
}


string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myReturnData);
```

Comment: Hello, this answer works, but is there a way to serialize the object to a javascript format like new {Name = "Myname"} would be serialized to {name: "MyName"}. Thank you

Comment: @LexyFeito I see noone has answered your question.
Use:
`var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };`
`settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());`
`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myReturnData, Formatting.Indented, settings);`

Comment: I have followed this working fine but if data or object contains more content then it throws Out Of Memory Exception. How to handle it ?

Comment: @MdAslam please follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask a new question

Answer (score 41):

Use .net inbuilt class [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
  JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  string json = js.Serialize(obj);
```

Comment: how to handle 'json.put("totalCount", total); ' ?