# Redirect with Ajax POST

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

i'm new with ajax and i'm trying to call a post action from an ajax method like that

```
 $(".buttonSelection").click(function () {

    selectedId = $(this).parents('tr:first').children('td:first').children('input:first').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        // Call MaSelection action method
        url: "/DemandeLocation/MaSelectionOffre",
        data: { id: selectedId },
        type: 'Post',
        success: function (msg) {
            window.location.replace('@Url.Content("~/DemandeLocation/MaSelectionOffre")');
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("something seems wrong");
        }
    });
    });
```

my post method goes with success  but instead of redirectin me to the MaSelection View it return the first view where i call the method, so i tried to put a "Success" fragment in my ajax method and i puted a location replace by "Ma selection" view but i know that the view lose the id so it become null, how can i do it with Ajax,

here my post action for more details

```
[HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Locataire")]
    public ActionResult MaSelectionOffre(string id)

    {
        int DemandeLocationGetbyId = Convert.ToInt32(id);

        var selectionOffre = db.SelectionOffreLocationSet.Where(model => model.DemandeLocationPublication_ID == DemandeLocationGetbyId).ToList();

        return View("MaSelectionOffre", selectionOffre);
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just pass the selectedId with the target url you are redirecting to?

Answer (score 1):

use `json` as datatype;

```
 $(".buttonSelection").click(function () {

    selectedId = $(this).parents('tr:first').children('td:first').children('input:first').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        // Call MaSelection action method
        url: "/DemandeLocation/MaSelectionOffre",
        dataType:"json",
        data: { id: selectedId },
        type: 'Post',
        success: function (msg) {
            window.location.href = msg.redirect;
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("something seems wrong");
        }
    });
    });
```

also you need this ;

[Convert object to JSON string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345382/convert-object-to-json-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: it's not a problem with data type, my action get the id and return the list of items, i tried this but it gave me something seems wrong

Answer (score 1):

If you want redirect page, after ajax call you should use

```
...
success: function (msg) {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("MaSelectionOffre", "DemandeLocation")';
},
...
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want replace result, use something like following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="updateTargetId">
    //table
        //tr
            //td
                //your button that has cssClass buttonSelection
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".buttonSelection").click(function () {

    selectedId = $(this).parents('tr:first').children('td:first').children('input:first').attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        // Call MaSelection action method
        url: "/DemandeLocation/MaSelectionOffre",
        dataType:"json",
        data: { id: selectedId },
        type: 'Post',
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#updateTargetId").html(msg);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("something seems wrong");
        }
    });
});
```

**CONTROLLER** (return PartialView)

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Locataire")]
public ActionResult MaSelectionOffre(string id)

{
    int DemandeLocationGetbyId = Convert.ToInt32(id);

    var selectionOffre = db.SelectionOffreLocationSet.Where(model => model.DemandeLocationPublication_ID == DemandeLocationGetbyId).ToList();

    return PartialView("MaSelectionOffre", selectionOffre);
}
```

Comment: here's the scenario, i call the MaselectionAction that return a list of item to the view MaSelection, the problem that when i put the retrun view with selectionOffre list it works as well as i want, but after the sucess of the action , it returns to the ajax and check sucess fragment, when i put  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("MaSelectionOffre", "DemandeLocation")'; the view lost  Selected list and return "The resource cannot be found".

Answer (score 0):

i changed my action to a get action and in my button i just added window.location.replace with link and ID

```
<button type="button" class="buttonSelection" onclick="window.location.replace('@Url.Content("~/DemandeLocation/MaSelectionOffre?id="+item.Publication_ID)')"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-cart"></span> </button>
```