# Pass a C# custom array to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I have the following C# array and I would like to pass it to JavaScript. What would be the best way to achieve it? Thank you?

```
public static List<ListDetail> GetMyList()
{
    List<ListDetail> myList = new List<ListDetail>();
    myList.Add(new ListDetail() { Id = 1, Name = "Party" });
    myList.Add(new ListDetail() { Id = 2, Name = "Course" });
    myList.Add(new ListDetail() { Id = 3, Name = "Home" });
    return myList.ToArray;
}
```

Comment: In what manner?  From server side code to a webpage?

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345382/convert-object-to-json-string-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JsonConvert to convert your objects into a JSON string, so they can be easily manipulated by JavaScript

```
// declare variable on your class
public string strJson; 
...  
// assign value in relevant method
strJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new myList);
```

All you need to do then is expose the string in your front-end website.

**If you're using webforms**, you could use `<%=strJson %>` inside a `<script>` tag.  Alternatively, you could use a Literal.

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xyz = <%=strJson%>;
    console.log(xyz);
</script>
```

**Or, if you're using MVC**, you could use `ViewData["Json"] = strJson;` in your controller, and then `@Html.Raw(ViewData["Json"])` inside a `<script>` tag in your View.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xyz = @Html.Raw(ViewData["Json"]);
    console.log(xyz);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  And then how can I convert fro JavaScript the JSON to an array?

Comment: You can use `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(strJson)` if its an array, or `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(strJson)` if its an object.  Or you can use `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to deserialize the string to a specific .NET class.