# Parsing multiple json files that are referencing each other in Unity3D

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to parse multiple json files that are referencing each other into C# class structure. 
Example:

Class json file

```
{
   "wizard" : 
   {
      "type" : "ice",
      "spells" : ["ice_orb", "ice_storm"]
   }
}
```

Spells json file:

```
{
   "spells" : 
   {
      "ice_orb":
      {
         "damage": 25,
         "cooldown": 2
      },
      "ice_storm":
      {
         "damage": 35,
         "cooldown": 4
      }
   }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
[Serializable]
public class IceOrb
{
    public int damage;
    public int cooldown;
}

[Serializable]
public class IceStorm
{
    public int damage;
    public int cooldown;
}

[Serializable]
public class Spell
{
    public IceOrb ice_orb;
    public IceStorm ice_storm;
}

[Serializable]
public class Wizard
{
    public string type;
    public List<Spell> spells;
}
```

Please do not suggest to merge everything in one file because it is not an option for me.

Comment: You may create partial classes to hold these.

Comment: you can convert the jsons to respected class and then can relate the class objects

Comment: @viveknuna, do you have a link to tutorial?

Comment: You can use Linq to join the relations after deserialization, but thats about as much automagic that I think you can get. edit: There is not point in having two classes with same behaviour

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11345478/366064

Comment: also it's better to overload a constructor with input parameter of type jsonObject in each of your classes. this way you can convert more easily