# Rewrite Curl in C#

Tags: c#, php, rest, api, httpwebrequest

I am trying to make a post request, but keep getting error 400 Bad Request in the response.

The request is to upload a pdf file for a customer. The example provided in the documentation is a curl command and i'm having difficulty recreating it in C#

This is the curl example:

```
curl -F "metadata=<test.json" -F "payload=@test.pdf" https://api.company.com/v1/documents/customer/customer-<Customer's GUID>/upload?authentication=<token>;
```

In the test.json file it stores the document name, type, category and description. (JSON format).

Here is my C# code

```
 byte[] pdfFile = File.ReadAllBytes(document path);
 string document = Convert.ToBase64String(pdfFile);

 Document docToUpload = new Document();
 docToUpload.name = "testDoc";
 docToUpload.format = "PDF";
 docToUpload.description = "this is a test";
 docToUpload.category = "19";

 List<Document> docs = new List<Document>();
 docs.Add(docToUpload);

 DocumentObjects docObject = new DocumentObjects();
 docObject.document = docs;

 //convert object to JSON 
 string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(docObject);

  WebRequest docRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.company.com/v1/documents/customer/customer-"+customerGuid+"/upload?authentication=" + token);

  using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(docRequest.GetRequestStream()))
  {
     streamWriter.Write(postData);
  }

  var responsedoc = (HttpWebResponse)docRequest.GetResponse();

  using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responsedoc.GetResponseStream()))
  {
    result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
```

Comment: Is "<Customer's GUID>" suppose to be there instead of a unique Guid?

Comment: It's a unique guide to represent the customer. The "token" is also a unique identifier.

Comment: in your code it does not seem like it is unique. You are adding "<Customer's GUID>" directly in the link and not the specific guid like you did with token..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was just using <customer's guid> as a place holder in the question. I'm actually passing the real guid.

Comment: Try using HttpWebRequest instead of WebRequest. (HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"https://api.company.com/v1/documents/customer/customer-"+customerGuid+"/upload?authentication=" + token);

Also use UserAgent:

req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";

Comment: One of the issues that I am having is that I do not understand how to pass both JSON data and a pdf file all at once.

Comment: Try looking at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345382/convert-object-to-json-string-in-c-sharp