# How to return JSon object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using a jQuery plugin that need a JSON object with following structure(I will be retrieving the values from database):

```
{ results: [
    { id: "1", value: "ABC", info: "ABC" },
    { id: "2", value: "JKL", info: "JKL" },
    { id: "3", value: "XYZ", info: "XYZ" }
] }
```

Here is my class:

```
public class results
{
    int _id;
    string _value;
    string _info;

    public int id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
    public string value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
        }
    }
    public string info
    {
        get
        {
            return _info;
        }
        set
        {
            _info = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the way I serialize it:

```
results result = new results();
result.id = 1;
result.value = "ABC";
result.info = "ABC";
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

But this will return only one row. Can you please help me in returning more than one result? How can I get the result in the format specified above?

Comment: Your `result` variable is a single item, not a collection. You need a collection if you want an array of items.

Comment: you  can look this link 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4/6201609#6201609

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm

Comment: @nercan: That has nothing to do with his question.. he is using James Newton-King's plugin.

Answer (score 37):

First of all, there's [no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). What you've got in your question is a JavaScript object literal (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation) for a great discussion on the difference). Here's how you would go about serializing what you've got to JSON though:

I would use an anonymous type filled with your `results` type:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    results = new List<Result>()
    {
        new Result { id = 1, value = "ABC", info = "ABC" },
        new Result { id = 2, value = "JKL", info = "JKL" }
    }
});
```

Also, note that the generated JSON has result items with `id`s of type `Number` instead of strings. I doubt this will be a problem, but it would be easy enough to change the type of `id` to `string` in the C#.

I'd also tweak your `results` type and get rid of the backing fields:

```
public class Result
{
    public int id { get ;set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string info { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, classes conventionally are `PascalCased` and not `camelCased`.

Here's the generated JSON from the code above:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "value": "ABC",
      "info": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "value": "JKL",
      "info": "JKL"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'd leave the IDs as `int` or whatever makes sense in code; Javascript can usually handle them just fine either way, so you might as well take advantage of strong typing while you can. There's always `.ToString()` if they need to be strings for transit.

Comment: @anaximander: That is true. I'd prefer `int` personally as well. I'll change it back and make a note. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: The code you posted is just not compiling. It's giving errors as "Type expected", "; expected", "invalid expression term ','", "a new expression requires () or [] after type", and "invalid expression term ()"

Comment: @user1640256: What version of the .NET framework are you using?

Answer (score 6):

You only have one row to serialize.  Try something like this :

```
List<results> resultRows = new List<results>

resultRows.Add(new results{id = 1, value="ABC", info="ABC"});
resultRows.Add(new results{id = 2, value="XYZ", info="XYZ"});

string json = JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(new { results = resultRows});
```

- Edit to match OP's original json output

** Edit 2 : sorry, but I missed that he was using JSON.NET.  Using the `JavaScriptSerializer` the above code produces this result :

```
{"results":[{"id":1,"value":"ABC","info":"ABC"},{"id":2,"value":"XYZ","info":"XYZ"}]}
```

Comment: This won't generate what the OP is asking for--he's generating an *object* with a single property `results`, not an array of results.

Comment: This does not produce the result the OP was asking for, its missing the object with the `results` property.

Comment: This would work if the OP wanted results broken out, but his root node is called results

Comment: No, results variable is of type `results` and resultRows is of type `List<T>`.

Comment: @ShaneBlake-I am using .net framework 2.0 so System.Web.Extension namespace is not available.

Comment: @0A0D: Client requirement. Can't change.

Comment: @user1640256: I find that odd, but OK