# JSON format is not supported by highchart

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, highcharts

I am creating a JSON file using the following code

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=INBDQ2WK2LBCD2S\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 10 x from test4 order by Id desc", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);

        DATA = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt, new Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting());
        Response.Write(DATA);
```

My JSON looks like

```
  [{"x":"58770"},{"x":"79035"},{"x":"84030"},{"x":"90145"},{"x":"95630"},{"x":"102580"},{"x":"108950"},{"x":"113615"},{"x":"118765"},{"x":"124055"}]
```

But I want something like,

```
[[58770,79035,84030,90145,95630,102580...]]
```

How do I achieve this,

I want this specific format for using this json for highchart

Comment: What are you selecting from the database?

Comment: I am selecting single column and last 10 data from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that on client side this way:

```
var d = [{"x":"58770"},{"x":"79035"},{"x":"84030"},{"x":"90145"},{"x":"95630"},{"x":"102580"},{"x":"108950"},{"x":"113615"},{"x":"118765"},{"x":"124055"}],
    dLen = d.length,
    ret = [];

for(var i = 0; i < dLen; i++) { 
    ret.push( parseInt(d[i].x, 10));
}

// ret contains: [58770, 79035, 84030, 90145, 95630, 102580, 108950, 113615, 118765, 124055]
```

Comment: and how do I get this JSON at client side?

Comment: Check some other similar questions, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441880/how-to-return-json-object).