# Add custom name to an array using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, arrays, list, datatable, json.net

I need to retrive the array of JSON object like this:

```
{ "MyCustomName": [ { "id": 0, "item": "item 0" }, { "id": 1, "item": "item 1" } ] }
```

instead of this:

```
{ [ { "id": 0, "item": "item 0" }, { "id": 1, "item": "item 1" } ] }
```

Here is the code i've use:

```
    using (SqlConnection con = conection.Conect())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelPeople", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyCustomName");  
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        List<Personal> ListOfPeople= new List<Personal>();

                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            Personal persona = new Personal();

                            persona.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"].ToString());
                        persona.Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
                        //add one row to the list
                        ListOfPeople.Add(persona);
                    }

                   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfPeople, Formatting.Indented);
                    Response.Write(json);
                }
            }
        }
```

Some help would be nice, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at this post [from another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441880/how-to-return-json-object)

In your controller change this part

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfPeople, Formatting.Indented);
Response.Write(json);
```

To:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    MyCustomName = ListadoDePersonal;
});
Response.Write(json);
```