# returning list or two dimension from Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I need to return list form Azure function. It can be list or any array but of course, it will be JSON internally.

Is it possible ? please guide if there is a sample code.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried, and if so - what problem have you faced?

Answer (score 0):

Here is and example of Azure function returning a property formatted JSON object instead of XML:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var myObj = new {name = "thomas", location = "Denver"};
    var jsonToReturn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
        Content = new StringContent(jsonToReturn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
    };
}
```

The screen shot:

[image]

For more details about return JSON from azure function, you could refer to this [blog](https://codehollow.com/2017/05/return-json-from-csharp-azure-function/).

Comment: You know that you've returned a JSON object without any Array, List etc.?

Comment: The return value is rely the content of JsonConvert.SerializeObject. If you want to return with list of JSON, this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441880/how-to-return-json-object?answertab=votes#tab-top) may help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function that returns a List of settings for an ERP that receives as parameter:

```
if (dataReader == null)
    req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
else
{
    List<ERPCompanySettingsResponse> settingsList = new List<ERPCompanySettingsResponse>();

    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        settingsList.Add(new ERPCompanySettingsResponse
                            {
                                SettingName = dataReader[0] != DBNull.Value ? dataReader[0].ToString() : null,
                                SettingValue = dataReader[1] != DBNull.Value ? dataReader[1].ToString() : null,
                                VATNumber = vatNumber
                            });
                        }

       return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, settingsList.ToArray());
```