# Best way to convert C# Class to JSON representation

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, json

I've got c# objects that I need references to in javascript for default population.  Currently I'm maintaining 2 different objects which is not that maintainable.

For example ( simplified for demo purposes ):

C#

```
public class Text
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

JSON

```
{
     'text': {
          name: undefined
     }
}
```

I know there is a number of ways to accomplish this but wondering if anyone has a recommended solution.  Thanks!

Comment: This question and answer are exactly what you need i think. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6201609/1483002

Comment: @DROPtableusers - evanmcdonnal response is preferred since it uses the new .net standard

Comment: glad you found what you needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally recommend json.NET. Getting the json of any object is as simple as;

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;

 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Text { Name = "test" });
```

There are a lot of other options but I've been using it since before there was json serilization support in .NET and I strongly prefer it over what is there now. In fact I think it's better in every way, if you want a big robust data layer I like it more and it's vastly superior for one off serilizations.

Comment: Thats perfect, didn't realize that was exposed like that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4.0 or above, you can use [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to look at this benchmark http://theburningmonk.com/2013/09/binary-and-json-serializer-benchmarks-updated/