# How to convert json object to string in C#?

Tags: c#, json

```
{
    "memberRegistration": [{
        "reference_mobile": "1",
        "reference_name": "r1",
        "member_id": "12"
    }, {
        "reference_mobile": "2",
        "reference_name": "r2",
        "member_id": "12"
    }, {
        "reference_mobile": "3",
        "reference_name": "r3",
        "member_id": "12"
    }, {
        "reference_mobile": "4",
        "reference_name": "r4",
        "member_id": "12"
    }]
}
```

I have a json object as shown above. How can I convert it to a string?
I want a string in this format;

```
@"[{""reference_mobile"":""1"",""reference_name"":""r1"",""member_id"":""12""},"+@"{""reference_mobile"":""2"",""reference_name"":""r2"",""member_id"":""12""},"+@"{""reference_mobile"":""3"",""reference_name"":""r3"",""member_id"":""12""},"+@"{""reference_mobile"":""4"",""reference_name"":""r4"",""member_id"":""12""}]";
```

Please help me to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)

Answer (score 1):

use [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(YourJson);
```

Comment: what i have to pass in your json

Comment: @TejParikh Your JsonString "{
    "memberRegistration": [{
        "reference_mobile": "1",
        "reference_name": "r1",
        "member_id": "12"
    }, {
        "reference_mobile": "2",
        "reference_name": "r2",
        "member_id": "12"
    }, {
        "reference_mobile": "3",
        "reference_name": "r3",
        "member_id": "12"
    }, {
        "reference_mobile": "4",
        "reference_name": "r4",
        "member_id": "12"
    }]
}"