# How to get Json data through LINQ in WCF?

Tags: c#, json, linq, wcf

I am new to WCF. I want to get Json formatted data using LINQ Query with Entity Framework. I am not able to return the value.

This is my code in Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
 UriTemplate = "getcontact")]

List<Tbl_Users> JSONDataAll();
```

This is my class code:

```
public List<Tbl_Users> JSONDataAll()
{
    var users = (from u in db.Tbl_Users select u);
    return users.ToList<Tbl_Users>();
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the service?

Comment: Like this i am calling.  http://localhost:53835/FslService.svc/getcontact

Comment: Please post the `Exception` being thrown and the `DataContract` for `Tbl_Users` class.

Comment: Have you looked at Newtonsoft.Json? You could then use return JsonConvert.Serialize(users)

Comment: Are you putting that link in a browser window? You may need to send the header `Accept: application/json` to see it in the browser.

Comment: @David Watts. Yes i am putting that link in a browser.

Comment: @David Watts. can you please tel me where i need to send the header

Comment: You can't do it with a browser, use a tool like Fiddler (every good web developer should use this! :)

Comment: while returning my data, the url becoming like this http://www.localhost.com:53835/FslService.svc/getcontact  and showing error like Server not found. I am not able to find how the localhost.com is adding to the url

Comment: Oh, you don't need the `.com`, just use `localhost:53835/FslService.svc/getcontact`.

Comment: No, i am putting the link like this localhost:53835/FslService.svc/getcontact . After that LINQ query executes and returns, the browser url becoming like this http://www.localhost.com:53835/FslService.svc/getcontact.

Comment: In relation to returning C# classes as a JSON string.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4

Answer (score 0):

try call instead of 
 localhost:53835/FslService.svc/getcontact

use the following method

```
https://127.0.0.0/FslService.svc/getcontact
```

Perhaps this will help

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use this?

Comment: Look at the following http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/627082/How-to-Consume-WCF-Service-using-JavaScript-Proxy   or http://www.bendewey.com/index.php/186/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [webHttpBehaviur](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) to your endpoint and when sending the request to add `Accept: application/json` header, can be done easily with Fiddler, or with a browser add-on.

Here you can see a good walkthrough of [WCF REST service with XML / JSON](http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/05/wcf-rest-service-with-xml-json-response-format-according-to-content-type-header/)