# Deserialize json string to object c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have a JSON string which needs to be deserialized into an object.

This is what I have tried :

Class :

```
public class trn
{
    public string visited_date { get; set; }
    public string party_code { get; set; }
    public string response { get; set; }
    public string response_type { get; set; }
    public string time_stamp { get; set; }
    public string trans_id { get; set; }
    public double total_amount { get; set; }
    public double discount { get; set; }
}
```

json string :

```
string json = "{\"trn\":{\"visited_date\":\"2015-04-05\",\"party_code\":\"8978a1bf-c88b-11e4-a815-00ff2dce0943\",\"response\":\"Reason 5\",\"response_type\":\"NoOrder\",\"time_stamp\":\"2015-04-05 18:27:42\",\"trans_id\":\"8e15f00b288a701e60a08f968a42a560\",\"total_amount\":0.0,\"discount\":0.0}}";

trn model2 = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<trn>(json);
```

and using json.net

```
trn model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<trn>(json);
```

but all the properties are initialized with null values.

Comment: check out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON represents an object with `trn` as a property within another object. So you need to represent that in your code, as well. For example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Transaction
{
    [JsonProperty("visited_date")]
    public DateTime VisitedDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("party_code")]
    public string PartyCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public string Response { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("response_type")]    
    public string ResponseType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("time_stamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("trans_id")]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("total_amount")]    
    public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("discount")]
    public double Discount { get; set; }
}

public class TransactionWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("trn")]
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{\"trn\":{\"visited_date\":\"2015-04-05\",\"party_code\":\"8978a1bf-c88b-11e4-a815-00ff2dce0943\",\"response\":\"Reason 5\",\"response_type\":\"NoOrder\",\"time_stamp\":\"2015-04-05 18:27:42\",\"trans_id\":\"8e15f00b288a701e60a08f968a42a560\",\"total_amount\":0.0,\"discount\":0.0}}";
        var wrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransactionWrapper>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(wrapper.Transaction.PartyCode);
    }
}
```

Note how I've used the `[JsonProperty]` attribute to allow the property names themselves to be idiomatic for .NET, but the JSON property names to still be used appropriately. I've also changed the types of `Transaction` and `VisitedDate`. Finally, it's slightly alarming that `total_amount` and `discount` are `double` values - that's really not suitable for currency values. Unfortunately, you may not be able to control that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @InvernoMuto says, your JSON string is an object with a nested object property, the inner object is the trn object. Your JSON string would need to be something like this to work:

```
string json = "{\"visited_date\":\"2015-04-05\",\"party_code\":\"8978a1bf-c88b-11e4-a815-00ff2dce0943\",\"response\":\"Reason 5\",\"response_type\":\"NoOrder\",\"time_stamp\":\"2015-04-05 18:27:42\",\"trans_id\":\"8e15f00b288a701e60a08f968a42a560\",\"total_amount\":0.0,\"discount\":0.0}";
```

I think Jon's answer is far more definitive however.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is a `Dictionary<string,trn>`, try yourself in this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tObjzK)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;



public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{\"trn\":{\"visited_date\":\"2015-04-05\",\"party_code\":\"8978a1bf-c88b-11e4-a815-00ff2dce0943\",\"response\":\"Reason 5\",\"response_type\":\"NoOrder\",\"time_stamp\":\"2015-04-05 18:27:42\",\"trans_id\":\"8e15f00b288a701e60a08f968a42a560\",\"total_amount\":0.0,\"discount\":0.0}}";

        var p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,trn>>( json );



        Console.WriteLine(p["trn"].party_code);
    }
    public class trn
    {
        public string visited_date { get; set; }
        public string party_code { get; set; }
        public string response { get; set; }
        public string response_type { get; set; }
        public string time_stamp { get; set; }
        public string trans_id { get; set; }
        public double total_amount { get; set; }
        public double discount { get; set; }
    }


}
```