# How to send model parameter to js in ASP net?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to send model parameter from div to script. This is my not working .cshtml file

```
@model List<Dialog>
@foreach (Dialog dialog in Model)
{
    <div onclick="SelectDialog(@dialog)"></div>
}
<script>
    function SelectDialog(dialog) {
        //work with dialog
    }
</script>
```

How can I send current dialog from view to script?

Comment: You want to turn a C# object to JSON, right? Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4

Comment: `Dialog` is a complex object. Inspect the html your generating - it will be `<div onclick="yourAssembly.Dialog></div>` (or whatever the `.ToString()` method of `Dialog` returns). What are you actually trying to do? What is `Dialog`?. Do you want to use the properties of `Dialog` in your script?

Comment: As a understood it is impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When addressing a model in the first line you should:

Index.cshtml

```
 @model IEnumerable<YourProject.Models.Dialog>
```

or

```
 @model YourProject.Models.Dialog
```

col1, col2 and col3 are your class objects

Class.cs

```
namespace YourProject.Models
{
public class Dialog    {
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Dialog> all = new List<Dialog>();
        ...
        return View(all);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know and have done it. I need to work with each dialog in script at my view when user click on  the div

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Dialog object, can you achieve the desired functionality by passing parameters to SelectDialog? For example: 
Instead of

```
function SelectDialog(Dialog d)
{
  if (d.id == 1)
    alert('first id');
  else
    alert('not first');
}
write:
function SelectDialog(int d)
{
  if (d == 1)
    alert('first id');
  else
    alert('not first');
}
```