# Ajax call returning string describing object instead of object

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm running C# with MVC in ASP.NET, and I've got an ajax call that's supposed to return a `list` of objects, but instead it's just returning the string `` "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Namespace.CustomObject]" ``

Clearly the data is making it back to the javascript, and returning `List<int>` doesn't change anything significant, so the object isn't at fault. Did I make a mistake in my ajax call that I've been missing, or do I need to use something other than `list`?

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: arrayOfInts
        contentType: 'application/json',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length) {
                doThisIfDataReturned(data);
            } else {
                doThisIfNoDataReturned(productIds);
            }
        }
    });
```

And the method it calls:

```
public List<CustomObject> MakeAList(int[] productIds)
    {
        //
        // create objectList
        //
        return objectList; //debugger shows that list is correct here
    }
```

Comment: You need something in place that will perform the serialization of the object.  What are you running server side?  MVC? WebForms?  How specifically does your request end up at `MakeAList`?

Comment: if you ask for json from client...need to respond with json

Comment: Something looks off with the serialization. It's doing the .ToString() representation of the list instead of the JSON serialized version of the return value. Can you show abbreviated code for your service including any attributes applied to the class/method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)

Comment: @Rod Probably not - there can be some very specific ways of encoding objects as json depending on what's going on here - may not need to resort to using manual serialization.  There's not enough information here to know if that's the case or not though.

Comment: @JamesThorpe MVC. Will edit that into the question.

Comment: `public JsonResult MakeAList(int[] productIds) { .... return Json(objectList);` }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C# you need to return a JSON object instead of a List.  I've done stuff like this in the past:

```
    public JsonResult myFunc()
    {
        ..... code here .....


        return Json(myList);
    }
```

Edit:
  Sometimes it is nice to see exactly what is being sent back before it is sent.  One way to accomplish this is to assign the return object to a variable, then return the variable.

```
    public JsonResult myFunc()
    {
        ..... code here .....

        var x = Json(myList);
        return x;
    }
```

This does exactly the same thing but is slightly easier to debug.