# Fastest way to create json in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a sample of data which is given below.

```
{
    "ditems": [
        {
            "type": "ditem",
            "name": "webmet.com",
            "ditem": 0,
            "links": [
                "www.abc.com/a",
                "www.sempo.org/"
                ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ditem",
            "name": "webmet.com/who-we-are/careers",
            "ditem": 2,
            "links": [
                "http://www.tele12.com/about",
                "http://tele12.com/life-at-teletech-en-US/about-teletech/"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "themes": [
        {
            "type": "theme",
            "name": "http://searchm.com/isr/agenda",
            "description": "",
            "slug": "http://searchm.com/isr/agenda-2"
        },
        {
            "type": "theme",
            "name": "http://www.sempo.org/",
            "description": "",
            "slug": "http://www.sempo.org/-2"
        }

    ]
}
```

Here is my code

```
 var InternalURLList = dtInternalURL.AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("URL")).Distinct().ToList();

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder ThemeSb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("{\"ditems\":[");

            if (InternalURLList.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < InternalURLList.Count; i++)
                {
                    var ExternalDomainList = GetExternalDomain(Domain_ID, InternalURLList[i]).AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("ExternalDomain")).Distinct().ToList();                   
                    sb.Append("{\"type\":\"ditem\",");
                    sb.Append("\"name\":");
                    sb.Append("\"" + InternalURLList[i] + "\",");
                    sb.Append("\"ditem\":" + i + ",");
                    sb.Append("\"links\":[");
                    if (ExternalDomainList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < ExternalDomainList.Count; j++)
                        {
                            sb.Append("\"" + ExternalDomainList[j] + "\"");
                             sb.Append((j != ExternalDomainList.Count - 1) ? "," : "]") ;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append("]");
                    }
                    sb.Append("}");
                    sb.Append((i != InternalURLList.Count - 1)?",":"]");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append("]");
                sb.Append(",");
            }

            DataTable dtDistinctDomain = GetDistinctExtDomain(Domain_ID);
            var ExternalDomain = dtDistinctDomain.AsEnumerable().Select(c => c.Field<string>("ExternalDomain")).Distinct().ToList();
            ThemeSb.Append(",\"themes\":[");
            for (int i = 0; i < ExternalDomain.Count; i++)
            {
                // For theme
                ThemeSb.Append("{\"type\":\"theme\",");
                ThemeSb.Append("\"name\":\"" + ExternalDomain[i] + "\",");
                ThemeSb.Append("\"description\":\"\",");
                ThemeSb.Append("\"slug\":\"" + ExternalDomain[i] + "-2" + "\"}");
                ThemeSb.Append((i != ExternalDomain.Count - 1)?",":"]");
            }
            ThemeSb.Append("}");
            string ConceptMapTheme = ThemeSb.ToString() ;
            string ConceptMapJSON = sb.ToString()+ThemeSb.ToString();
            return ConceptMapJSON;
```

I am trying to make json in C# using `StringBuilder`. The `for` loop is taking too much time to generate the json. The table contains more than 2,00,000 records. How to create json in a fastest way using C#?

Comment: Take a look at [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Why bother manually creating when you can use NewtonsoftJSON using either web api or an mvc web application.

like so :

`Public JsonResult Index(){return Json(JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet,True);}`

Comment: Also take a look in [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: you have https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Rubens - That functionality is built in to Visual Studio; you don't need to use a website. Go to the top menu in VS Edit>Paste Special>Paste JSON As Classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)

Comment: Simple google 'C# to json' will give you plenty of results.

Comment: You are asking how to create a JSON or Serialize the json object?

Comment: To serialize or create the json object you have to use Newtonsoft.Json. Best way to create a json is serialize the class with property to Json object.

Comment: I have updated my code. `for` loop is taking too much time to scan all the node. How should I modify to make it faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the [Newtonsoft.Json nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) in your project.
Then you just need to call the serializer :

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSerialize);
```

Comment: This answer is not helped me.

Comment: With the code you added, it appears you don't define any object to serialize. Why not defining the object to serialize and then serializing it instead of using the StringBuilder class ?