# unable to convert linq query output into into json data in .net

Tags: c#, json, linq

i want to get 5 top ten records of Temperature column and want to convert into json data. i tried like this but not getting desired values

**{"success":true,"sensorsdata":{"WaterTemperature":"33.33"}}**

```
  using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
                {
                    var parkingSlot = DB.ParkingSlots.OrderByDescending(x => x.CurrentTime).Select(x => x.WaterTemperature).Take(5);

                    return Json(new { success = true, sensorsdata = new { WaterTemperature = "33.33" } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
```

Comment: The error details would be helpful

Comment: Look at the following post - might help: [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)

Comment: i have updated my question.kindly help me out how to get 5 values form table

Comment: Why aren't you using the values you read into parkingSlot in your return statement?

Comment: return Json(new { success = true, sensorsdata = new { WaterTemperature = parkingSlot. } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

after parkingslot im not getting watertempreture property

Comment: I would assume you need to do something like this:

double[] tempratures = parkingSlot.ToArray();
return Json(new { success = true, sensorsdata = new { WaterTemperature = tempratures } }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

However i do not know what Json() does, but you can put a breakpoint after you project your data into an array (or list, if you wish), to check what data you downloaded.