# How call WebAPI method in MVC and send the json object to it

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I need to call this method in MVC controller and pass the UpdateRequest  object as json format. how I can do that?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("updatecertificate")]
    public void updatecertificate([FromBody] UpdateRequest certificatereviewed)
    {
       loansRepository.updatecertificate(certificatereviewed.Id, certificatereviewed.CertificateReview);
    }
```

and this is the input class:

```
 public class UpdateRequest {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool CertificateReview { get; set;}
}
```

this is how I call and send separate variable but now I like to send the class object in json format.

```
  private async Task UpdateFundingCertificateReviewed(int id, bool fundingCertificateReviewed)
    {
        await httpClient.PostAsync(string.Format("{0}/{1}", LoanApiBaseUrlValue, updatecertificate),null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally like Newtonsoft.Json to serialize the object.

```
private async Task UpdateFundingCertificateReviewed
        (int id, bool fundingCertificateReviewed)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", LoanApiBaseUrlValue, updatecertificate);
        var updateRequest = new UpdateRequest { Id = 1, CertificateReview = true};
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(updateRequest);
        await client.PostAsync(url, data);
    }
}
```

**FYI:** Async without return is not a good practice. However, it is out of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform an object into a JSON string, see this question: [Turn C# object into a JSON string in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4)
`var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);`

Is this what you are after or do you want to know how to construct the http request with a JSON object in the body?

Answer (score 0):

your questionis not very clear, what is the outcome that you expect ?
If you want to **POST** an request with JSON body you can check the @Win comment, 
however if you want to make an **Response** from the Api to the MVC project you should do a bit more steps tough. :))