# Insert comma into string where two brackets are touching (C#)

Tags: c#, json, string, delimiter

I'm trying to write a JSON file in C#, and I have a problem where I want to seperate each object with a comma (',') for it to be valid JSON, however I can't figure out how to do this. I've searched if there is a way you can search for a specific pattern in a string (in my case it would be '}{') and a regular expression might work, but I don't know how to create one.

The final result should look like

```
      '},{'
```

instead of

```
      '}{'.
```

Here is my code so far:

```
    private void loopThroughArray()
    {
        string json = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
            {
                MyObject t = array[i];
                json += new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(t);
                //this writes the json to the file but without comma seperator
            }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"<MyFilepath>\json.txt", "{\"json\":[" + json + "]}");
       //this writes the json to a file that and is in a json array called 'json' 

    }
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own JSON serializer? Should use something like http://www.newtonsoft.com/json if you can.

Comment: I'll look at the Newtonsoft one, I know its good for deserialisation. I thought the JavaScriptSerializer was as good as I would get.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at different ways of serialising JSON as per @Measuring 's suggestion and discovered that this was the easiest method in my opinion:

```
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject);
```

Works perfectly, thanks @Measuring!

Comment: Using a JsonSerializer is always a good idea to serialize to JSON

Comment: You can even do this way: [`File.WriteAllText(@"<MyFilepath>\json.txt", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { json = array }));`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vjsDHe)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with `@Measuring` it seems like an over complication to write your own when there are tools which can be used as identified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4).

Nonetheless you could do the following...

```
string json = "";
for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++){
    MyObject t = array[i];
    json += new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(t);
}

string pattern = "\}{\";
string replacement = "},{";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(json, replacement);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be solved by `string.Join` and a bit of Linq

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = string.Join( ",", array.Select( e => serializer.Serialize(e) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this:

```
json += new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(t);
```

Is creating a `{json object}`. Your solution might be as easy as appending a `,` after like:

```
json += new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(t) + ",";
```

Edit (responding on your comment):
You can easily skip the last loop with an inner check.

```
json += new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(t);
if (i < array.Count - 1) json += ",";
```

Alternatively you could cut the for-loop 1 item short and add the last item after the loop.

Comment: It _almost_ is. It just adds one extra , to the end of the file before the array closes :(

Comment: string.Join( ",", array.Select( e => serializer.Serialize(e) )

Answer (score 0):

It's far more efficient to use a StringBuilder than += and you should avoid creating reusable objects within loops.

Keeping as close to your code as possible, you could try:

```
private void loopThroughArray()
{
   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   var json = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < array.Count; i++)
   {
      MyObject t = array[i];
      json.Append(serializer.Serialize(t));
      if (i < array.Count)
         json.Append(",");
   }
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"<MyFilepath>\json.txt", "{\"json\":[" + json.ToString() + "]}");
}
```

But it may be simpler to try:

```
private void loopThroughArray()
{
   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   var json = serializer.Serialize(array);
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"<MyFilepath>\json.txt", "{\"json\":" + json.ToString() + "}");
}
```

But, if I were doing it I'd use Json.Net's JsonConvert on an anonymous type:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(
    @"<MyFilepath>\json.txt",
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {
        json = array
    }));
```

You can get Json.Net from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/).

Comment: Note that your last suggestion works with JavaScriptSerializer just fine...

Comment: You're right Alexei.  I just prefer Json.Net for **so** many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

JsonNet is indeed easier to use, but in your case it feels like 
 `JavaScriptSerializer` works fine. Presumably you expect "{json:[...]}" as result - serializing  `new {json = array}` instead of just `array` will produce that output:

```
var finalJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new {json = array});
```

Side note: please avoid manual string manipulation when constructing JSON or XML -it is not worth the effort and result in most cases is somewhat wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Kevin would it not be possible to replace the string using regex expressions,

```
/}{/g
```

and replace with

```
},{
```