# Serialize and deserialize JSON object from separate classes without need to have stand-alone class?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Is it possible to form an object from two classes and then serialize it to JSON, and when deserialize it back be able to get those two objects.
say I have: an object of `Student` and a `List<Course>` 
is it possible to combine these two objects in one JSON object.
I need this because building up a class for every JSON object would be very exhausting in the project I'm working on!

Comment: I now see that I misinterpreted your question a little. Since the (de)serializer map everything on properties/fields, you'd probably want to create a wrapper object, like @Vecchiasignora said. Otherwise the deserializer wouldn't know what to deserialize to which object.

Comment: @stealthjong using a KeyValuePair also solves the problem

Comment: @mafii Only in the case that you have only two objects to serialize. Otherwise you'd still have to fallback on a wrapper object

Comment: @stealthjong there are also tuples. It's ugly I know, but he specified that he doesn't want to create a wrapper...

Comment: @Mafii I know, but that's just plain dumb. For the sake of not creating a wrapper class, you're jumping through hoops everywhere. And it isn't helping readability too. You'd almost be better off serializing everything manually. That way you also don't have to create a wrapper class, and because of the key you should know in how to deserialize. But that wouldn't make sense, and neither does using KVpairs and tuples to serialize/deserialize. BRAHIM Kamel's code already isn't readable anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`Is it possible to form an object from two classes and then serialize it to JSON`*

Yes it is possible  to  do this  just use `Merge` from [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm)

for example here is an example

```
   class  Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Course
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } 
    }

         var std = new Student() {Name = "foo"};
        var lstCours = new List<Course>() { new Course(){Title = "math"}};
        var stdJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {student=std});
        var lstCoursJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new{Cours= lstCours});  
        JObject jObjectStd = JObject.Parse(stdJson);
        JObject jObjectLstCours = JObject.Parse(lstCoursJson);
        jObjectStd.Merge(jObjectLstCours,new JsonMergeSettings(){MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Concat}); 
        Console.WriteLine(jObjectStd.ToString());
```

here what you get as a merge

```
{
  "student": {
    "Name": "foo"
  },
  "Cours": [
    {
      "Title": "math"
    }
  ]
}
```

to deserialize this is pretty simple with JSON.net

```
var stdParsed = JObject.Parse(json).Property("student").Value.ToString();
             var lstCoursParsed = JObject.Parse(json).Property("Cours").Value.ToString();
            var stdDes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(stdParsed);
            var lstCoursDes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Course>>(lstCoursParsed);
```

Comment: And how to deserialize it back to the two objects?

Comment: Hope  this help  :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible, and is actually very straightforward to do.

Say you have your two objects like this:

```
var student = new Student { Name = "Joe Schmoe" };

var courses = new List<Course>
{
    new Course { Title = "Underwater Basket Weaving 101" },
    new Course { Title = "History of Pancakes 102" }
};
```

On the serializing side, just use an anonymous object to combine your objects together and then serialize that:

```
var anon = new { Student = student, Courses = courses };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anon, Formatting.Indented);
```

Here is the JSON you would get:

```
{
  "Student": {
    "Name": "Joe Schmoe"
  },
  "Courses": [
    {
      "Title": "Underwater Basket Weaving 101"
    },
    {
      "Title": "History of Pancakes 102"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can combine as many objects together as you need to in this way. 
On the flip side, you can deserialize to a dynamic variable (which is a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) behind the scenes) and then recreate your original strongly-typed objects from it using `ToObject<T>()`.

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var student = obj.Student.ToObject<Student>();
var courses = obj.Courses.ToObject<List<Course>>();
```

Round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OKJBg2

Alternatively you can use deserialize-by-example to deserialize back to an anonymous object if you don't like the dynamic variable / `JObject` idea.  To do that, you first create an empty anonymous object in the same shape as the JSON to use as a "template" and then pass it along with the JSON to  `JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType`:

```
var template = new { Student = new Student(), Courses = new List<Course>() };
var anon = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, template);

Student student = anon.Student;
List<Course> courses = anon.Courses;
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Inz0r8

Comment: but I'll need to use `JObject` to deserialize it back?

Comment: The dynamic object actually *is* a `JObject` behind the scenes, so yes.  Alternatively, you could deserialize back to an anonymous object using deserialize-by-example if you don't want the `dynamic` / `JObject`.

Comment: This seems like the best solution. All other solutions result in de facto the same, but with more confusing or redunant code compared to this solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Serialize a `KeyValuePair<Student, List<Course>>` and deserialize to the KeyValuePair again.

```
var student = ...;
var courses = ...;

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new KeyValuePair<Student, List<Course>>(student, courses));
```

Then, deserialize it this way:

```
var pair = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyValuePair<Student, List<Course>>>(json);
var student = pair.Key;
var courses = pair.Value;
```

This is a workaround, but it's easy to understand, and very easy to use (compared to JObject or a class to combine them).

Answer (score 0):

Just Create `new Class` which has those 2 objects like this

```
public class StudentWithCours
{
    public Student student { get; set; }

    public List<Course> course { get; set; }
}
```

after that you can serialize/deserialize the class exemplar like this

.......

```
StudentWithCours myObject = new StudentWithCours();
//your some logic here]
var serilizedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
var deserilizedObject =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StudentWithCours>(serilizedObject);
```

Comment: Pretty good answer, if you ask me. I'll straighten out the -1

Comment: This will lead to a huge change in my application, which as my question stated, don't need to do.

Answer (score -1):

It is. This one-liner depends on the Newtonsoft NuGet package, which is popular and better than the default serializer.

```c#
var myObject = ...;
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

Documentation: **[Serializing and Deserializing JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)**

Other possibility:

You could use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class (add reference to System.Web.Extensions):

```c#
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

Other options are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4), where you can find above two answers, along with many others.

Piece of code:

```c#
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();

    public class Course
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}

var student = new Student
{
    Name = "Jack",
    Courses = new List<Student.Course>
    {
        new Student.Course() {Name = "MATH", Code = "MA"},
        new Student.Course() {Name = "Science", Code = "SC"}
    }
};
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student);
var studentDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(str);
```

Try it out for yourself