# How to read a C# SortedList type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I've created an ASP.NET MVC5 app with SignalR for the backend and using javascript for the front end. My web service returns a C# object defined like this:

```
public class MarkableItemList
{
    public SortedList<string, MarkableItem> Items { get; set; }

    public bool ItemsSelectable { get; set; }

    public MarkableItemList()
    {
        Items = new SortedList<string, MarkableItem>();
    }
}
```

My JavaScript function on the web page looks like this:

```
var updateState = function (state) {
    //console.log("Item count: " + state.Items.Count());
    console.log("ItemsSelectable: " + state.ItemsSelectable);
};
```

When I run the page, it correctly returns the state of `ItemsSelectable` but I cannot work out how to obtain the value from the `SortedList`. I'd like to get the count and then iterate over the list.

I've commented out the Count console log but I've tried all variants of:

- length
- count
- camel casing/pascal casing
- with and without brackets

In the console I either get

> "Item null: undefined"

or I get

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'Count'"

Any suggestions on how I can do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: inspect that serialized json object or that state object and you will know..

Comment: [Turn C# object into a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6201529/463206)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a SoredtList has a very obscure Json state so you cannot parse it so easily. I temporarily changed it to a List and it appears to produce normal Json that could be parsed. Thus I've now changed my code to use a List.