# Linq SUM values error

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

```
public async Task<WalletTrans> getCredits(int id) 
{
    var credit = await _context.walletTrans.ToAsyncEnumerable().Where(r => r.Id == id).Sum(s => s.quantity);
    return credit;
}
```

I have that code above using C#.net core that supposedly returning a summation of a filed in the table.

But I'm having this error.

> "Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to
>   'ProjectName.Models.ModelName' [ProjectName]"

Comment: Your method return type is `WalletTrans`, but you're returning `decimal` value from `Sum()` function. Adjust return type as `decimal` or assign sum value to any `decimal` property that `WalletTrans` class has.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I still don't get it. Can you give me sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a sample as you asked:

```
public async Task<decimal> getCredits(int id)
{    
    var credit = await _context.walletTrans.ToAsyncEnumerable().Where(r => r.Id == id).Sum(s => s.quantity);   
    return credit;
}
```

Comment: how can I return this as a JSon?

Comment: do you mean a string in json format or some jobject from newtone library? Yes you can, just return not credit, but new JObject(credit) or whatever.

Comment: Take a look at the following SO thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net

Answer (score 0):

This will answer my question regarding on how can I return it as a **JSON Object**

```
public async Task<object> getCredits(int id){
    dynamic response = new JObject();
    try {
          decimal credit = await _context.walletTrans.ToAsyncEnumerable().Where(r => r.Id == id).Sum(s => s.quantity);
          response.Credit = credit;
          return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response.Error = e;
            return response;
        }
}
```

Thanks for All your help :D

Comment: I would avoid dynamic if you can, and just use correct types. 

`public async Task<JObject>…` 

and then to fill in values, `response["Credit"] = credit` or `response["Error"] = e`.