# .Net Core 2.1 return list with dependent type by id

Tags: c#, .net

For example, I have orders model:

```
int Id
string Name
User user
```

How to return something like that in response when getting orders, when orders table has user id column:

```
{
id: 1,
name: "Order 1",
user: "Some username"
}
```

I know it can look easy question, but I'm new to C# and .NET and don't exactly know the terminology and for what tutorial should I look for.

Comment: The latter is called [json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6201529/1997232).

Comment: go through these documentations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core

Comment: Yes, im asking how to merge two tables in response from .net side. I know i want return json, i already returning orders, but wanted to return advanced structure, mapped from 2 tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need is to return a Data Transfer Object (DTO).
Create another class, say `OrderDTO`.

```
public class OrderDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

Then map your `order` object(s) to `OrderDto` before returning them as your response.

```
 var oderDto = new OrderDto { 
      Id = orderModel.Id,
      Name = orderModel,
      User = oder.User.Username // or some other property you want
 };
```

[Automapper](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) would be a very good library to use for the mapping part.

Your actions will then look something like this

```
 public ActionResult GetStuff()
 {
      var orderModel = ....; // do your thing to get your order
      var responseObj = Mapper.Map<OrderDto>(orderModel);
      return StatusCode(200, responseObj); 
 }
```

The framework will then do the conversion from the DTO class to Json for you.

Comment: Awesome response. Thanks.