# Json post is invalid unless is wrapped in brackets

Tags: c#, json

In my code i send a post to rest service such as:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requesturi, mydata);
```

mydata collection is translated to Json   by PostAsJsonAsyn as:

```
{
    "queryid" : "GetNames",
    "@StartDate" : "1/1/2019",
    "@EndDate" : " "2/1/2019"
}
```

However the server return Http 400 reponse unless the jason object is wrapped in brackets (tested in Postman)

```
[
   {
       "queryid" : "GetNames",
       "@StartDate" : "1/1/2019",
       "@EndDate" : " "2/1/2019"
   }
]
```

Is there any way to add the brackets to json object passed by PostAsJasonAsyn  method

Thanks

Comment: Brackets indicate array, so it seems that is expected. You will have to create mydata to be a list/array/enumerable. Can you show us what mydata is?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(requesturi, new[] { mydata } );
```

Comment: yes that should do it. although it might be better to declare mydata as an array.

Answer (score -1):

That's becuase standard of `JSON`. you should search on the internet first:

https://jsonlint.com/

[How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net/6201609)

[Working With JSON in C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-json-in-C-Sharp/)