# How can I use web api to get SQL Server values and convert to JSON

Tags: c#, json

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString="data source=*;initial catalog=*;User ID=*;Password=*";
conn.Open();

SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, conn);

SqlDataReader dr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
```

How should I use SqlDataReader to get SQL Server values (3 cols and many rows) and turn them into JSON type that Android App can parse it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)

Comment: You need to read the entire data from database into an array or a list of anonymous type and then use Newtonsoft JSON library to call JsonConvert.SerializeObject API to convert the list/array to JSON.

Comment: Thank you and I want to know more about how to use SqlDataReader and make the result convert into JSON, thank you.