# How to form the JSON string using the variables available?

Tags: c#, json

I have the variables which has values in as follows:

```
var Name = "ABC";
var address = "cde";
var id = 2;
```

I want to form the JSON string using above as

```
var jsonObj = {"Name":"cde","Address":"cde","id":2};
```

these variable are not static, but here I had shown just for the understanding. 
These variable gets assigned some values based on some logic , but end  goal is to have the jsonObj value as

```
{"Name":"cde","Address":"cde","id":2}
```

Comment: create model class and convert into json it's full-fill your requirement.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)

Comment: @Prasad : Its perfect!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [json seralization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm).

> SerializeObject() Serializes the specified object to a JSON string.

To seralize values to json format, you need to create one model class, which will look like,

```
public class JsonObj
{
  string Name { get; set; };
  string Address { get; set; };
  int Id { get; set; };
}
```

Now create instance of `JsonObj` class, by assigning values to each property.

```
JsonObj jObject = new JsonObj()
{
  Name = "ABC" 
  Address = "cde"
  Id = 2
};
```

Now use [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json.htm) library to serialize your object to json string

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject);
```

As @Csharpest suggest, you can use Anonymous type as well to serialize

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Name = "ABC", Address = "cde", Id = 2 }); //Here you need not to create model class and instantiation as well
```

Comment: Could also use an anonymous class, don't have to specify a class object.