# How to convert SQL Server query to JSON

Tags: html, json, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, view

I need to build a table in a view using the result of this SQL Query

```
    SELECT f.empresaid,
       e.fantasia                  AS Empresa,
       f.filialid,
       f.fantasia                  AS Filial,
       u.consultorid               AS ConsultorID,
       cs.nome                     AS Consultor,
       ''                          AS Midia,
       fp.campoextra,
       Count(DISTINCT p.usuarioid) AS Total,
       Count(DISTINCT u.ativacao)  AS TotalAtivos,
       Iif(Count(DISTINCT p.usuarioid) > 0, ( Cast(
       Count(DISTINCT u.ativacao) AS DECIMAL) / Count(DISTINCT p.usuarioid) ), 0
       ) * 100
                                   AS Porcentagem
FROM   formas_pagamento fp
       INNER JOIN usuarios u
               ON u.forma_pagamentoid = fp.forma_pagamentoid
       INNER JOIN pagamentos p
               ON p.usuarioid = u.usuarioid
                  AND p.tipo = 'MTU'
       INNER JOIN cartoes c
               ON c.usuarioid = u.usuarioid
                  AND c.dependenteid = 0
       INNER JOIN midias m
               ON m.descricao = u.midia
       INNER JOIN consultores cs
               ON cs.consultorid = u.consultorid
       INNER JOIN filiais f
               ON f.filialid = u.filialid
       INNER JOIN empresas e
               ON e.empresaid = f.empresaid
WHERE  c.dependenteid = 0
       AND u.cadastro > '2019-07-01'
       AND u.cadastro < '2019-08-01'
       AND u.filialid = 3
GROUP  BY f.empresaid,
          e.fantasia,
          f.filialid,
          f.fantasia,
          u.consultorid,
          cs.nome,
          fp.campoextra
ORDER  BY empresaid,
          filialid,
          consultor,
          campoextra
```

Which gives me this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWack.jpg), the table in the view should be created with the structure as follows [table structure and organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggDc3.jpg). I was trying to load this query data directly from my ViewModel List but that went heavy, if I could have a json array as following :  [JSON](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=66428e4b0522410cac86fc1185b35ee4) I could build the table with that desired structure more easily, can anyone help ? Thanks !

----------------------------------EDIT-------------------------------------

```
public List<ViewModelOrigemEConsultor> GetConsultorOrigem ()
    {
        var Lista = new List<ViewModelOrigemEConsultor>();
        /*string SQL = SQL QUERY GOES HERE */

        var cnn = CnnDB.OpenDB();
        using (cnn)
        {
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, cnn);
            cnn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                decimal Porcentagem = 0;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Porcentagem = (decimal)(Convert.ToInt32(reader["TotalAtivos"]) / Convert.ToInt32(reader["Total"]));
                    Lista.Add(new ViewModelOrigemEConsultor
                    {
                        EmpresaID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EmpresaID"]),
                        Empresa = reader["Empresa"].ToString(),
                        FilialID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FilialID"]),
                        Filial = reader["Filial"].ToString(),
                        ConsultorID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ConsultorID"]),
                        Consultor = reader["Consultor"].ToString(),
                        Midia = reader["Midia"].ToString(),
                        FormaPagamento = reader["FormaPagamento"].ToString(),
                        Total = Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:N}", reader["Total"])),
                        TotalAtivos = Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:N}", reader["TotalAtivos"])),
                        Porcentagem = Convert.ToString(string.Format("{0:N}", Porcentagem))
                    });
                };
            }

        }; 

        return Lista; 
    }
```

**MODEL**

```
public class ViewModelOrigemEConsultor
{
    public int EmpresaID { get; set; }
    public string Empresa { get; set; }
    public int FilialID { get; set; }
    public string Filial { get; set; }
    public int ConsultorID { get; set; }
    public string Consultor { get; set; } 
    public string Midia { get; set; }
    public string FormaPagamento { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public string TotalAtivos { get; set; }
    public string Porcentagem { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a model/class array representing that structure and populate it with your query. After that, it's a simple case of using something like JSON.NET to serialise the class into JSON.

Comment: See this post for a hint : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net

Comment: This site will convert the JSON you already have to a c# class. http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Have you tried to use Newtonsoft.Json? Here's some example: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the list of objects populated and are just looking to convert it to JSON simply use something like https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json and then serialize the list to json. In this case it would be similar to:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```