# Json array problem.. i need really help --- .net core mvc

Tags: json, .net, deserialization

These are my classes

> ```
> <pre>///Thank you for helping me....
>   public class Sport
>     {
>         public string id { get; set; }
>         public string name { get; set; }
>     }
>     public class Category
>     {
>         public string id { get; set; }
>         public string name { get; set; }
>         public string country_code { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class Competition
>     {
>         public string id { get; set; }
>         public string name { get; set; }
>     }
>     public class Season
>     {
>         public string id { get; set; }
>         public string name { get; set; }
>         public string start_date { get; set; }
>         public string end_date { get; set; }
>         public string year { get; set; }
>         public string competition_id { get; set; }
>     }
>     public class Stage
>     {
>         public int order { get; set; }
>         public string type { get; set; }
>         public string phase { get; set; }
>         public string start_date { get; set; }
>         public string end_date { get; set; }
>         public string year { get; set; }
>     }
>     public class Round
>     {
>         public int number { get; set; }
>         public string other_sport_event_id { get; set; }
>         public int cup_round_sport_event_number { get; set; }
>         public int cup_round_number_of_sport_events { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class Group
>     {
>         public string id { get; set; }
>         public string name { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class SportEventContext
>     {
>         public Sport sport { get; set; }
>         public Category category { get; set; }
>         public Competition competition { get; set; }
>         public Season season { get; set; }
>         public Stage stage { get; set; }
>         public Round round { get; set; }
>         public IList<Group> groups { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class SportEventProperties
>     {
>         public bool lineups { get; set; }
>         public bool extended_player_stats { get; set; }
>         public bool extended_team_stats { get; set; }
>         public bool ballspotting { get; set; }
>         public bool commentary { get; set; }
>         public bool fun_facts { get; set; }
>         public bool goal_scorers { get; set; }
>         public string scores { get; set; }
>         public bool game_clock { get; set; }
>         public bool deeper_play_by_play { get; set; }
>         public bool deeper_player_stats { get; set; }
>         public bool deeper_team_stats { get; set; }
>         public bool basic_play_by_play { get; set; }
>         public bool basic_player_stats { get; set; }
>         public bool basic_team_stats { get; set; }
>         public string lineups_availability { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class Coverage
>     {
>         public string type { get; set; }
>         public SportEventProperties sport_event_properties { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class Competitor
>     {
>         public string id { get; set; }
>         public string name { get; set; }
>         public string country { get; set; }
>         public string country_code { get; set; }
>         public string abbreviation { get; set; }
>         public string qualifier { get; set; }
>         public string gender { get; set; }
>         public Statistics statistics { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class Ground
>     {
>         public bool neutral { get; set; }
>     }
>     public class Referee
>     {
>         public string id { get; set; }
>         public string name { get; set; }
>         public string nationality { get; set; }
>         public string country_code { get; set; }
>         public string type { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class SportEventConditions
>     {
>         public Ground ground { get; set; }
>         public IList<Referee> referees { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class Venue
>     {
>         public string id { get; set; }
>         public string name { get; set; }
>         public int capacity { get; set; }
>         public string city_name { get; set; }
>         public string country_name { get; set; }
>         public string map_coordinates { get; set; }
>         public string country_code { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class SportEvent
>     {
>         public string id { get; set; }
>         public DateTime start_time { get; set; }
>         public bool start_time_confirmed { get; set; }
>         public SportEventContext sport_event_context { get; set; }
>         public Coverage coverage { get; set; }
>         public IList<Competitor> competitors { get; set; }
>         public SportEventConditions sport_event_conditions { get; set; }
>         public Venue venue { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class PeriodScore
>     {
>         public int home_score { get; set; }
>         public int away_score { get; set; }
>         public string type { get; set; }
>         public int number { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class Clock
>     {
>         public string played { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class SportEventStatus
>     {
>         public string status { get; set; }
>         public string match_status { get; set; }
>         public int home_score { get; set; }
>         public int away_score { get; set; }
>         public IList<PeriodScore> period_scores { get; set; }
>         public Clock clock { get; set; }
>     }
>     public class Statistics
>     {
>         public int yellow_cards { get; set; }
>         public int yellow_red_cards { get; set; }
>         public int red_cards { get; set; }
>         public int corner_kicks { get; set; }
>         public int shots_total { get; set; }
>         public int shots_on_target { get; set; }
>         public int shots_off_target { get; set; }
>         public int shots_blocked { get; set; }
>         public int ball_possession { get; set; }
>         public int free_kicks { get; set; }
>         public int offsides { get; set; }
>         public int goal_kicks { get; set; }
>         public int throw_ins { get; set; }
>         public int shots_saved { get; set; }
>         public int fouls { get; set; }
>         public int injuries { get; set; }
>         public int cards_given { get; set; }
>         public int substitutions { get; set; }
>     }
>
>
>
>     public class Totals
>     {
>         public IList<Competitor> competitors { get; set; }
>     }
>
>
>
>     public class Summary
>     {
>         public SportEvent sport_event { get; set; }
>         public SportEventStatus sport_event_status { get; set; }
>         public Statistics statistics { get; set; }
>     }
>
>     public class SoccerInformation
>     {
>
>         public DateTime generated_at { get; set; }
>         public IList<Summary> summaries { get; set; }
>
>         
>     }
> </pre>
>
>
> And the some of the json data
>
>
> <pre>
>  "summaries": [
>         {
>             "sport_event": {
>                 "id": "sr:sport_event:24534090",
>                 "start_time": "2020-11-23T12:00:00+00:00",
>                 "start_time_confirmed": true,
>                 "sport_event_context": {
>                     "sport": {
>                         "id": "sr:sport:1",
>                         "name": "Futbol"
>                     },
>                     "category": {
>                         "id": "sr:category:297",
>                         "name": "Azerbaycan",
>                         "country_code": "AZE"
>                     },
>                     "competition": {
>                         "id": "sr:competition:709",
>                         "name": "Premier Lig"
>                     },
>                     "season": {
>                         "id": "sr:season:77839",
>                         "name": "Premier Lig 20\/21",
>                         "start_date": "2020-08-21",
>                         "end_date": "2021-05-31",
>                         "year": "20\/21",
>                         "competition_id": "sr:competition:709"
>                     },
>                     "stage": {
>                         "order": 1,
>                         "type": "league",
>                         "phase": "regular season",
>                         "start_date": "2020-08-21",
>                         "end_date": "2021-05-31",
>                         "year": "20\/21"
>                     },
>                     "round": {
>                         "number": 10
>                     },
>                     "groups": [
>                         {
>                             "id": "sr:league:51295",
>                             "name": "Premier League 20\/21"
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 },
>                 "coverage": {
>                     "type": "sport_event",
>                     "sport_event_properties": {
>                         "lineups": false,
>                         "extended_player_stats": false,
>                         "extended_team_stats": false,
>                         "ballspotting": false,
>                         "commentary": false,
>                         "fun_facts": true,
>                         "goal_scorers": true,
>                         "scores": "live",
>                         "game_clock": true,
>                         "deeper_play_by_play": false,
>                         "deeper_player_stats": false,
>                         "deeper_team_stats": false,
>                         "basic_play_by_play": false,
>                         "basic_player_stats": false,
>                         "basic_team_stats": false
>                     }
>                 },
>                 "competitors": [
>                     {
>                         "id": "sr:competitor:382568",
>                         "name": "Sabah FC",
>                         "country": "Azerbaycan",
>                         "country_code": "AZE",
>                         "abbreviation": "SBH",
>                         "qualifier": "home",
>                         "gender": "male"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "id": "sr:competitor:281393",
>                         "name": "Sabail FK",
>                         "country": "Azerbaycan",
>                         "country_code": "AZE",
>                         "abbreviation": "SAB",
>                         "qualifier": "away",
>                         "gender": "male"
>                     }
>                 ],
>                 "sport_event_conditions": {
>                     "ground": {
>                         "neutral": false
>                     }
>                 }
>             },
>             "sport_event_status": {
>                 "status": "closed",
>                 "match_status": "ended",
>                 "home_score": 2,
>                 "away_score": 1,
>                 "winner_id": "sr:competitor:382568",
>                 "period_scores": [
>                     {
>                         "home_score": 2,
>                         "away_score": 0,
>                         "type": "regular_period",
>                         "number": 1
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "home_score": 0,
>                         "away_score": 1,
>                         "type": "regular_period",
>                         "number": 2
>                     }
>                 ]
>             },
>             "statistics": {
>                 "totals": {
>                     "competitors": [
>                         {
>                             "id": "sr:competitor:382568",
>                             "name": "Sabah FC",
>                             "abbreviation": "SBH",
>                             "qualifier": "home",
>                             "statistics": {
>                                 "yellow_cards": 2,
>                                 "cards_given": 2,
>                                 "substitutions": 3,
>                                 "corner_kicks": 3,
>                                 "injuries": 1
>                             }
>                         },
>                         {
>                             "id": "sr:competitor:281393",
>                             "name": "Sabail FK",
>                             "abbreviation": "SAB",
>                             "qualifier": "away",
>                             "statistics": {
>                                 "yellow_cards": 1,
>                                 "cards_given": 1,
>                                 "substitutions": 4,
>                                 "corner_kicks": 4
>                             }
>                         }
>                     ]
>                 }
>             }
>         }
> </pre>
>
>
> and i used to json to c# these codes:
>
> <pre>
> var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();///Thank you for helping me....
>                 
> return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SoccerInformation>(content);///Thank you
> ```

im trying to list matches to learn how to get datas from json to .net core mvc
i deserialized json to c# object via using the json2c# website
but i can't reach the some of the classes like

- name of the competitors one by one...
- first period scores and scond period scores

im trying to do this at the view part of the MVC
i send the model but i can't list them via using Foreach loop in the view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

1. First verify that your json string adheres to the 'SoccerInformation' class. I don't find a generated_at field in your json.
2. Secondly, verify that all your json Keys are same as your class property names.
3. Thirdly, try accessing these with JObject.