# Array to JSON (key/ Value)

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I would like achieve Array to JSON object conversion in C# code.

Array : [a,b,c,d,e,f]

Json: `{"a":"b","c":"d","e":"f"}`

I tried to serialize the Array using newtonsoft and the output is not in a key value format. The input is an array of strings and the output need to be in JSON format key/value format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)

Comment: It looks like you should iterate over your array, taking alternate values as keys or values, adding them to whatever JSON library representation you're using (JObject). Which JSON library are you using, and have you tried anything and got stuck?

Comment: Also, what type `Array`?  Is it `List<string>`, `List<object>` or something else?  How is it defined?  Is it deserialized from JSON, or constructed in memory?

Comment: Thanks for all responses. I tried serialize of the object (newtonsoft) and the output is not a key value format. The input is array of string and the output need to be in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Given a `string []` array, you can convert it to a dictionary using LINQ, then serialize the dictionary.

E.g. using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net):

```
var dictionary = array.AsPairs().ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Value);
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sZIDFO).

Or, to serialize with [system.text.json](/questions/tagged/system.text.json) do:

```
var newJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dictionary, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sG15tP).

Both options use the extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<(T Key, T Value)> AsPairs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return AsPairsEnumerator(enumerable ?? throw new ArgumentNullException());
        static IEnumerable<(T key, T value)> AsPairsEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        {
            bool saved = false;
            T key = default;
            foreach (var item in enumerable)
            {
                if (saved)
                    yield return (key, item);
                else
                    key = item;
                saved = !saved;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And generate the result

```json
{
  "a": "b",
  "c": "d",
  "e": "f"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to achieve through while loop.

Comment: @Anshu - you're welcome.  If the question is answered please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86978).