# Convert an object to JSON, then download that JSON as a text file [Asp.net core]

Tags: c#, json, file, asp.net-core, download

### Info and code:

I am designing a UI where the user can design an object to meet their needs. Afterwards, I want them to be able to click a button to download a file containing the JSON representation of this object. A jquery click listener will use ajax to hit the endpoint on the controller when the button is clicked. Currently, the endpoint looks like this:

```
   // GET: api/Missions/DownloadMission?id
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Missions/DownloadMission{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult DownloadMission(int id)
    {
        Mission toDownload = db.Missions.Find(id);
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toDownload);
    }
```

As you can see, the mission object's Id is provided to controller, and the mission is grabbed from it. My problem is that I do not know how to convert the object into JSON in a way that I can then write said JSON into a file, and prompt the user to download it.

---

### Things I have tried:

1. 

```
  using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            while(missionJson.nex)
        }
        return File(stream, "text/plain");
    }

//I tried playing around with this type of set up, but could still not get the intended results
```

2. 

```
   byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(data);
    var output = new FileContentResult(bytes, "application/octet-stream");
    output.FileDownloadName = "download.txt";

    return output;
```

3. 

```
    Mission toDownload = db.Missions.Find(id);
    string fileName = @"~\Mission.txt";
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }  
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
            serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, toDownload);
            }
            return File(fs, "Mission.txt");
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
    }
// In this case, "File()" isnt recognized, but this is probably the closest i've been
```

4. I have looked through questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)

---

### Problems:

1. Like I said earlier, I don't know how to go from object to Json to a file
2. basically all tutorials I can find online are very outdated, or require a filepath, presuming you are providing a pre-existing file, which I am not.

Comment: Have you tried to simply `return Ok(toDownload);` this will return the json object without serialization

Comment: @Jawad I need to have the user download a file containing said JSON rather than just returning the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. > Like I said earlier, I don't know how to go from object to Json to a file

   1. You can use the **[System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1#how-to-write-net-objects-as-json-serialize)** namespace to serialize and deserialize JavaScript Object Notation (JSON).
   2. `string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast);`
2. > basically all tutorials I can find online are very outdated, or require a filepath, presuming you are providing a pre-existing file, which I am not.

   1. You can return **FileContentResult**.
   2. You can check the example below.
   3. Code

      ```
       [HttpGet("DownloadMission/{id}")]
       public FileContentResult DownloadMission(int id)
       {
           Mission toDownload = new Mission { Id = 1, name = "test" };
           string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(toDownload);
           var fileName = "test.txt";
           var mimeType = "text/plain";
           var fileBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString);
           return new FileContentResult(fileBytes, mimeType)
           {
               FileDownloadName = fileName
           };
       }
      ```
   4. Result

      [image]

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Missions/DownloadMission{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult DownloadMission(int id)
{
    var toDownload = db.Missions.Find(id);
       
    // if you set this, the browser asks the user to save 'export.json'
    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export.json");

    // return content as json with your default json serializer settings
    return new JsonResult(toDownload);
}
```

Like pointed out before, replace the `IHttpActionResult` with `IActionResult`, that's the right return type for ASP.NET Core.

I didn't try how it behaves with larger objects, maybe there is some optimization needed for that.

---

Alternatively you can also set the header in a more "fancy" way, that will properly escape your file name and gives you some additional properites to set.

```cs
HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = "export.json",
    Inline   = false
}.ToString());
```