# Json(JToken.Parse(response)) returns empty array

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-5

I have used HttpClient to consume an API and in turns i'm getting the response as serialized string from response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result as mentioned below,

```
"{\r\n  \"responseCode\": 400,\r\n  \"errors\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"errorCode\": \"RPM400\",\r\n      \"errorMessage\": \"A program already exists.\"\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}"
```

I want to deserialize this as

```
{
  "responseCode": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "RPM400",
      "errorMessage": "A program already exists."
    }
  ]
}
```

Then i have to send it to the UI, the return type in the ASP.Net MVC 5 ActionMethod is ActionResult.

I have tried using **Json(JObject.Parse(response)) and Json(JToken.Parse(response))** but i am getting the empty response in the postman as below

```
[
    [
        []
    ],
    [
        [
            [
                [
                    []
                ],
                [
                    []
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

The same **Json(JObject.Parse(response))** is working in another application which is ASP.Net Core 2. Could you provide some help on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I turn a C# object into a JSON string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net)

Comment: Yes @NoahBoegli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [stackOverflow's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net) marked answer, i had to use the **using System.Web.Script.Serialization;** for the Deserialization then it worked because my .Net Framework was 4.7.2