# SQL Server Data to Kafka in real time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I would like to add real time data from SQL server to Kafka directly and I found there is a SQL server connector provided by https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/sqlserver/

In the documentation, it says that it will create one topic for each table. I am trying to understand the architecture because I have 500 clients which means I have 500 databases and each of them has 500 tables. Does it mean that it will create 250000 topics or do I need separate Kafka Cluster for each client and each cluster/node will have 500 topics based on the number of tables in the database?

Is it the best way to send SQL data to Kafka or should we send an event to Kafka queue through code whenever there is an insert/update/delete on a table?

Comment: I highly doubt all tables actually need to be put into Kafka? If you maintain 100 database servers, are you prepared to maintain 100 Kafka clusters (at least 300 more servers)? And I've never used the Debezium connector, but I'm fairly sure it can read multiple tables in a database from one connector (and yes, schema changes are usually part of the CDC logs)

Comment: @OneCricketeer Are you saying we would need 100 Kafka Clusters, one for each database? or we can have multiple nodes inside the cluster. Can we have 2 clusters with 10 nodes inside each of them
Do you have any recommendation of moving real time sql data to kafka? How it can be done?

Comment: Debezium is the common recommendation. I just personally haven't needed it because we write data to Kafka then write to SQL instead of the other way around... And I don't have a recommendation for your architecture, but you'll obviously need to isolate your "clients" in some way such that one Kafka cluster outage doesn't affect another client

Comment: @OneCricketeer I thought about writing data to Kafka but that brings up the question what if someone who is sending event to Kafka adds incorrect data or data to sql is committed and now event cannot be send. You have to build the whole process around it. Do you know if one sql connector can connect to multiple databases?

Comment: Well, if the events are strongly-typed (e.g. Avro or Protobuf), then having malformed data is possible, although unlikely. Regarding the question, did you see the property called `database.names` - https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.7/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-property-database-names

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah, I saw that and it says it only supports one at a time and it is experimental and should not be used in production which means one connector for each database so it won't work for microservices because we will have to create way too many connectors

Comment: I've ran a connect cluster of at least 10 nodes with hundreds of connectors before for the S3 sink connector... The heap space eventually became a concern, but it worked

Comment: @OneCricketeer You mentioned that you drive data to Kafka first and then write to SQL. What is the structure of the message when there is an update or insert to the table? Are you sending some json structure or just SQL statement as a message in Kafka event?

Comment: By default in the JDBC Sink connector, the same record key performs an update. Non-existing keys are an insert

Comment: @OneCricketeer How are you handling scenarios where some of column updates have a trigger which updates something else? Is there a way to send events to Kafka for those triggers?

Comment: Those events would require Debezium, yes. But like I said, we haven't had a need for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With debezium you are stuck with one table to one topic mapping. However, there are creative ways to get around it.

Based on the description, it looks like you have some sort of product that has SQL Server backend, and that has 500 tables. This product is being used by 500 or more clients and everyone has their own instance of the database.

You can create a connector for one client and read all 500 tables and publish it to Kafka. At this point you will have 500 Kafka topics. You can route the data from all other database instances to the same 500 topics by creating separate connectors for each client / database instance. I am assuming that since this is a backend database for a product, the table names, schema names etc. are all same, and the debezium connector will generate same topic names for the tables. If that is not the case, you can use [topic routing SMT](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.7/transformations/topic-routing.html).

You can differentiate the data in Kafka by adding a few metadata columns in the topic. This can easily be done in the connector by adding SMTs. The metadata columns could be client_id, client_name or something else.

As for your other question,

> Is it the best way to send SQL data to Kafka or should we send an event to Kafka queue through code whenever there is an insert/update/delete on a table?

The answer is "*it depends!*".
If it is a simple transactional application, I would simply write the data to the database and not worry about anything else.

The answer is also dependent on why you want to deliver data to Kafka. If you are looking to deliver data / business events to Kafka to perform some downstream business processing requiring transactional integrity, and strict SLAs, writing the data from application may make sense. However, if you are publishing data to Kafka to make it available for others to use for analytical or any other reasons, using the K-Connect approach makes sense.

There is a licensed alternative, Qlik Replicate, which is capable of something very similar.

Comment: That is great answer. My follow up is that Won't creating and maintaining separate connectors for each client become a nightmare because 500 is just an example, there are 10,000 clients and with microservices architecture you can have 500,000 databases which means connectors for each database now.
Also, I do not want topics to be table names. It has to be domain based because others can use the same topics but the events will be different.

Comment: If you have 10,000 database, you are going to need separate processes to read data out of them. It would be an overhead for sure. If publishing data to Kafka is needed, I would then bake that logic into the application code. Depending on the downstream SLA and consistency requirements, I would design the implemtation accordingly. e.g making the sink to Kakfa optional and async process.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have many clients, so a specialized solution will be better, a specialized program running as service p example, to get change track from SQL Server and send to KAFKA or direct to your clients without the use of KAFKA. One delphi or python application to do this wil be better, the cons is you will need some good developer to program this.

About Debezium you need to know it suports only CDC and not CT from SQL Server, do y need really CDC (Capture Data Change)? No way by CT (Change Track)? If you have the CDC active in your SQL Server, think about all Deltas writed on disk, so dependes of your application but analize about this, maybe a great volume of data will be on CDC tables. So other soluction <> Debezium, can be better if you don't need CDC really, but if you need CDC, Debezium is OK.

About KAFKA, I think it is the better free ready solution at the moment.

And about Real Time, in true, with this solution is posslbe to be Near Real Time.