# Posting code snippet as a multi lined string json to API

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to write an application in c# that allows me to post a snippet of code to the textsynth api.

```
try
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.textsynth.com/v1/engines/gptj_6B/completions"))
            {
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer API_KEY");
                request.Content = new StringContent("{\"prompt\": \"" + message.Replace("\n", "\\n") + "\", \"max_tokens\": " + textBox2.Text + " }");
                request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
                this.Text = "Waiting for AI response...";
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                var jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                MessageBox.Show(jsonData);
                AiResponse aiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AiResponse>(jsonData);
                previousReponse = aiResponse.text;
                return aiResponse.text;

            }
        } catch (Exception e)
```

the message string contains as an example:

```
t = 0, p = 0, q = 0;

int num1, num2;

cout << "enter two numbers" << endl;
cin >> num1 >> num2;

t = t + num1;
```

The API will return this message to me:

expecting ',' or '}'

I know this has to do with `request.Content = new StringContent("{\"prompt\": \"" + message.Replace("\n", "\\n") + "\", \"max_tokens\": " + textBox2.Text + " }");`

and im sure its has to do with the format of the code im sending into the json. any help?

Comment: You may want to use an actual JSON parser to construct the JSON string for you.

Comment: @gunr2171 Do you have a recommended method of parsing given my current method of posting?

Comment: That has nothing to do with multiline, but you are not handling the `"` correctly. That's a common mistake when someone tries to create a json string by hand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net Don't create a JSON string yourself (using string concatination).

Comment: @gunr2171 Serializing a class worked thanks