Implementing Generics/Abstracts/Interfaces with serialization
I have a couple of classes that need to be serializable using DataContractSerializer, however I am trying to create a generic Class called XMLDocument, that allows for a WeatherData, RSSDocument, and a ConfigFile (all classes) to take its place. In the scenario a the three classes all Inherit from XMLDocument. This all works fine, however I run into an issue in another class called Slides, which is a generic class and Takes in a XMLDocument as a type.
Ive tried abstract which cant be serialized, ive tried making the XMLDocument class a Generic but that also doesnt seem to work.
How should I implement a generic/abstract/interface to get this to work?
public class Slide<DocumentType> where DocumentType : XMLDocument
{
    [DataMember]
    public DocumentType Page{ get; set; }
//more code down here...
}

Main window is where my error pops up, the closest I've gotten was making a constructor for the Slide class that takes and overrides the  type, like so
List<XMLDocument> slides = new Slide<XMLDocument>(RSSDocument); 
but it makes it unserializable
Main Window
static RSSDocument RSSDocument = new RSSDocument();

Slide<RSSDocument> slide = new Slide<RSSDocument>();
List<Slide<XMLDocument>> slides = new List<Slide<XMLDocument>>(); 
public MainWindow()
{
    
    InitializeComponent();
    slides.AddRange(slide.ReadSerializedSlides());
    SetTimers();
    slides.Clear();
    slides.AddRange(MediaRefresh(slide.ReadSerializedSlides()));

}

XMLDocument Class
[DataContract]
[XmlInclude(typeof(RSSDocument))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(WeatherData))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(GatherConfig))]
public class XMLDocument
{
    public void SerializeDocument()
    {
        string filename = @"\\motnas\mofilesvr\isystems\apps - IT and utilities\ Programs\DisplayBoardsConfigs\" + 
            this.GetType().ToString().Replace("DisplayBoard.Classes.", "") + ".txt";
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(this.GetType());
        serializer.WriteObject(fs, this);
        fs.Close();
    }
    public object DeserializeDocument()
    {
        string filename = @"\\motnas\mofilesvr\isystems\apps - IT and utilities\ Programs\DisplayBoardsConfigs\" +
            this.GetType().ToString().Replace("DisplayBoard.Classes.", "") + ".txt";
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(this.GetType());
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        XmlDictionaryReader reader =
        XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        var XMLDoc = serializer.ReadObject(reader);
        fs.Close();
        return XMLDoc;
    }
    public virtual Page CreatePage()
    {
        return new Page();  
    }
}

RSSDocument Class
[DataContract]
public class RSSDocument : XMLDocument
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public string Body { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
    //Other Functions
}

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Is there any particular reason you are using XML anyway? Why not JSON, which is more modern and much easier to use

For this application no, besides to get a better grasp of it, my industry still uses communication protocols made in the 70s, but is starting to move towards XML so I figured Id get used to it before that change happens.

You might want to convince them to jump a generation and move to modern REST and gRPC protocols

I wish I could but I dont have any sway with the big 3 lol if you ever want a nightmare of data exchange i can send you the documentation and just see how much of an improvement that XML actually is, even the begin <> characters arent standardized in the systems we use!!! GM uses ! ford uses ^ and chy uses * and they send you these 20 page documents for all their marker characters, those are just examples but i wanted to let you know how bad it is lol

@Charlieface — Modern?! Is it even a relevant reason? Look, DataContractSerializer is capable of serializing any object graphs. DataContractJsonSerializer — only trees. Who needs only trees if, in any non-trivial programming, we almost always work with arbitrary data graphs, that is, with unlimited circular references? Besides, in the context of the present question, DataContractJsonSerializer cannot add anything new, not even simplicity.

@SergeyAKryukov What makes you think I was talking about DataContractJsonSerializer when much better options exist? As documented "For most scenarios that involve serializing to JSON and deserializing from JSON, we recommend the APIs in the System.Text.Json namespace." Other alternatives include Newtonsoft.Json. All these options handle recursive graphs perfectly well, see eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/preserve-references

@Charlieface: What makes me think you were talking about DataContractJsonSerializer? Well, just this: “Why not JSON, which is more modern and much easier to use”. I understand that you are talking about JSON, and not about this particular serializer, but it looks like the inquirer uses Data Contract. Did you mean some other serializer? Sorry for the misunderstanding then, but please clarify. What exactly did you mean?

@SergeyAKryukov I rarely hear of people using that serializer. Either System.Text.Json or Newtonsoft.Json are the most popular. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/how-do-i-turn-a-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net

@Charlieface — Got it. Thank you, sorry for the confusion.
